# AngularJS - Extra blank option added when i use ng-repeat in select tag

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am facing some issue on select tab when using in ng-repeat.
On Stackoverflow i found many solution related to my broblem but i am not able to solve my broblem.

Here is my code..
on the top of page i define my controler

```
<ion-view view-title="Product" ng-controller="productCtrl as pd">
```

and on controller

```
self.pdata = response;
```

On html page my code is..

```
<div ng-if="pd.pdata.optionid.length > 0" class="prodetail" ng-repeat="x in pd.pdata.optionid">
    <h5>{{x.title}}</h5>
    <select name="{{x.title}}" ng-model="pd[x.title]" style="right:5px;">
      <option ng-repeat="y in pd.pdata.optionvalue[x.option_id]" value="{{y.value_id}}" selected>{{y.title | uppercase}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

here my select tab is in ng-repeat loop
so that every time my ng-model is define dynamically.

My Problem is:-extra blank option added using ng-repeat in select tag

Comment: If you want to get rid of blank option. Select first item in your controller. See this answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select?rq=1

Comment: As i told already..
my select tab is dynamically created. so that how i assign value to ng-model ?

Comment: You stated your problem, but not what you are trying to achieve. Do you always want the first option to start as selected?

Comment: @SureshRatten you can use `ng-init` to initialize your `ng-model` this way you won't get an empty value in the dropdown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

modify your `select` tag like this, it's a bit mouthful but works alternatively you can also keep your `option` tag and remove `ng-options` from my `select` tag.

```
<select ng-init="pd[x.title] = pd[x.title] || pd.pdata.optionvalue[x.option_id][0].value_id" name="{{x.title}}" ng-model="pd[x.title]" style="right:5px;" ng-options="y.value_id as y.title.toUpperCase() for y in pd.pdata.optionvalue[x.option_id]">
</select>
```

here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/825/)

Comment: Yes its help me but i am not able to show selected first option.

Comment: I have done it for the first option that is there in the `Array` by default but for example if you want to persist this change.. like when `pd[x.title]` is already initialized it'll have that option there

Answer (score 0):

Initially problem seems to be here

> value="{{y.value_id}}"

see more here [The empty option is generated when a value referenced by ng-model doesn't exist in a set of options passed to ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-(

Answer (score 0):

use a hard coded empty value

```
<option value="" ng-if="false"></option>
```