# Why is my directive (using link) not appearing and allowing ng-model to see it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been trying to resolve the issue from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select) that has to do with temporary empty `<select>` options because `ng-model` doesn't match an option.

The solution to use the following line works perfectly, but only when I drop that HTML directly in:

```
<option style="display:none" value="">(select)</option>
```

I have a directive created to standardize the "(select)" text and create that empty option when needed:

**empty-default-option.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function EmptyDefaultOptionDirective() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element) {
                element.prepend('<option style="display:none" value="">(select)</option>');
            }
        };
    }

    angular.module('utils.empty-default-option', [])
        .directive('emptyDefaultOption', EmptyDefaultOptionDirective);
}());
```

This doesn't work when used in the HTML file:

**context.html**

```
<select class="form-control"
        ng-model="context.contextChoice"
        empty-default-option>
            <option ng-repeat="choice in context.choices_data | orderBy:'id'">{{choice.first_name}} {{choice.last_name}}</option>
</select>
```

(**context.js** sets `contextChoice = ""`, so I don't think it's that. `controllerAs: 'context'`, also.)

I still get a temporary blank empty option, which to me means my directive option wasn't seen. I feel like this has to do with link versus controller, perhaps, or timing of when things are scanned or checked, but I'm having trouble finding answers.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: don't use `ng-repeat` for `<option>` use `ng-options` on the `<select>` instead see this doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: That does not change the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the right idea about the problem. A coworker pointed me towards this answer.

In the directive definition, the inserting of the `<option>` needs to happen earlier, so use `compile:` instead of `link:`:

```
compile: function compile(tElement) {
    tElement.prepend('<option style="display:none" value="">(select)</option>');
}
```