# Find item with specific ID and select it in dropdown

Tags: html, angularjs, select, default

Hi I've got follow object:

```
        myList = {
            Items: [
                {
                    ID: -1,
                    Name: "Default item"
                },
                {
                    ID: 0,
                    Name: "Some item"
                },
                {
                    ID: 12,
                    Name: "Item 1"
                }
            ]
        };
```

I loop this object with ng-options in my select like this:

```
<select ng-options="option as option.Name for option in myList.Items"></select>
```

It shows me my items in my list, but the dropdown has the first time also a empty item and this is default. After I click on one of my items, the empty removes and my selected item is in the list. How can I search for the item with ID = -1 and select this as default in my list without the empty one? I tried it with this:

```
let myDefault = myList.Items.find((item:any) => item.ID == -1);
```

It finds my item, but how can I set it as default in my list?

Thanks and cheers.

Comment: You should assign first option to ng-model (which is missing from your code btw) of your select. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select

Comment: @Keammoort Thanks, look at the answer, which is marked as correct. I edited it. With ng-model and find(), I can set it now as default, no matter if it's the first index or last. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add `ng-model` to `select` tag

```
 <select ng-model="select" 
         ng-options="option as option.Name for option in myList.Items">
 </select>
```

and in controller

```
 $scope.select = $scope.myList.Items.find((item:any) => item.ID == -1);
```

Comment: Hi and thanks, I edited you're code a little bit: I need a solution for select the item with ID == -1 in every case, also when it's not at the first index in the list -> so I added the ng-model (you were right with this) and add him the item with ID == -1, which I find in the list with find(). Thanks and cheers..

Answer (score 1):

Init your select's model to the first item in the array:

```
<select ng-init="selectedItem = myList.Items[0]" 
        ng-model="selectedItem" 
        ng-options="option as option.Name for option in myList.Items">
</select>
```