# AngularJS data binding with select tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I cannot figure out why data binding is not working on a select tag, as the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) specifies.

This is my select element:

```
<select id="start-type" ng-model="startType">
  <option value="day-of-week">Day of the week</option>
  <option value="month">Month</option>
  <option value="month-day">Day and month</option>
  <option value="year">Year</option>
  <option value="year-month">Month and year</option>
  <option value="local-time" selected>Time</option>
  <option value="local-date">Date</option>
  <option value="local-date-time">Date and time</option>
</select>
<label for="start-type">Start type</label>
```

The issue is that whenever an item is selected the `$scope.startType` model is never changed. It's always blank.

I have tried defining `$scope.startType` in my controller but I don't see why that would change anything because it should work as it already is. And of course, it didn't help.

I have gone through several working examples, but I can't see what I am missing here.

Edit: I figured out what's happening. The CSS framework I am using didn't have Angular in mind at all. It is rendering a custom view for a select using its own divs and layout, while hiding the actual select element. But they didn't even hook the select action into the hidden select, so the angular directives or data binding are never being triggered... Any clue on how I could put it all together?

Comment: "so the angular directives or data binding are never being triggered... Any clue on how I could put it all together?" - this needs to be asked as a separate question

Comment: @jusopi yeah I know, I found out about the actual issue after creating this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to bind to a pre selected value on the select's `ng-model`, you need to use `ng-options` instead.

```
<select id="start-type" 
        ng-model="startType" 
        ng-options="type.value as type.label for type in startTypes">
```

Where `startTypes` is defined on your controller:

```
$scope.startTypes = [{value:'day-of-week', label:'Day of Week'}, ...]
```

#### edit

Per @John S's comment below, you might want to add a default/blank option when the `$scope.startType == undefined` so that the UI renders correctly.

```
<option ng-selected="true" value="">select a market vertical</option>
```

source = [Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select/36893473#36893473)

Comment: In my experience this directive will not behave properly unless you have just one option tag that looks like `<option value=""></option>`. Other than this this answer is the right way to do it.

Comment: agreed, and I wish the angular team would've done a better job at handling such cases.  I did answer a related issue here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select/36893473#36893473

Comment: it is actually in the AngularJS docs but they dont make a big deal of it. I missed it several times. Generally what happens is you will get the wrong index selected on the model. Super confusing.

Comment: isn't there a way to make it work with fixed values in the html? The css framework I am using doesn't render the options properly if used in this fashion. It only does the other way.

Comment: @dabadaba it may be a value/reference type issue. Try changing $scope.startTypes to $scope.something.startTypes

Comment: @JohnS No, you didn't udnerstand me. The options are showing up but they're not being rendered properly by the css framework, it looks awful. That's why I want to define a fixed select with its options instead of having them in the controller.

Comment: Ok this was not the issue at all. Check out my edit.

Comment: @dabadaba Gotcha, this is still the "Angular" way to do it. What is the CSS framework you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I can see it working. Check out the snippet below

- Make sure you have the controller and the app declared correctly
- Also use try using `ng-options` and have the values come from the controller like in [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) example.

```js
angular.module('demo', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
  $scope.logModelValue = function() {
    console.log($scope.startType);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DemoController">
    <label for="start-type">Start type</label>
    <select id="start-type" ng-model="startType" ng-change="logModelValue()">
      <option value="day-of-week">Day of the week</option>
      <option value="month">Month</option>
      <option value="month-day">Day and month</option>
      <option value="year">Year</option>
      <option value="year-month">Month and year</option>
      <option value="local-time" selected>Time</option>
      <option value="local-date">Date</option>
      <option value="local-date-time">Date and time</option>
    </select>
    <span>{{startType}}</span>
    <button ng-click="logModelValue()">Console log model value</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

**EDIT**
Looks like the trouble is with getting materializecss and angular working together. You could either write your own angular wrappers over materializecss or use this library [angular-materialize](https://github.com/krescruz/angular-materialize)

Comment: I have tried setting up `ng-change` on the select tag and `ng-click` on any of the options to trigger a dummy method that logs something and none work.

Comment: Updated the snippet. I have added ng-change as well. It works. Can you try as in the snippet above?

Comment: Yeah I tried something like that and as I said nothing is logged. The `ng-change` directive isn't being triggered.

Comment: Can you post your entire code here? Not sure how I can help without seeing the whole thing!

Comment: I copied the select block directly from my project. What else would you need?

Comment: Well for a start your html file, ng-app, controller declaration...etc From looking at the code you posted it should work just like in my answer, but need more information to help you

Comment: Read your edit. Try using https://github.com/krescruz/angular-materialize which has got angular wrappers for materializecss.

Answer (score 1):

I would use ng-model, and ng-change. Ng-change would be evaluated whenever the selected value is changed.