# ng-table select filters show double blank items in IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, html-select, ngtable

I am using an ng-table with select filters:

```
<table ng-table="wrCtrl.waitingRoomTable" show-filter="true" cellspacing="0">
   <tr ng-repeat="item in $data" ng-form name="form-data">

      <td data-title="'Status'" filter="{importStatusDisplayText: 'select'}" filter-data="ctrl.importStatuses" sortable="'importStatusDisplayText'">
          <span id="importStatus">{{::item.importStatusDisplayText}}</span>
      </td>

  </tr>
 </table>
```

The source array (`importStatuses`) is:

```
[ {id: 0, displayText: "Created"},
  {id: 1, displayText: "Error"},
  {id: 2, displayText: "Success"},
  {id: 3, displayText: "Rerun"},
  {id: 4, displayText: "Resolved manually"},]
```

And it generates the following result in IE (tested with IE 11 and Edge). On Chrome it shows the drop down correctly.

`importStatusDisplayText` is a property that takes the selected displayText value out of the importStatuses array.

[image]

This seems to be a problem with IE and ng-table as I get the same result on ng-table [examples page](http://ng-table.com/#/filtering/demo-select).

Is there a way to fix this behavior also for IE?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post:
[Add a NgTableParams setting to modify the default "-" value for SELECT filters](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/pull/654#issuecomment-127095189)

In my case I had to update ng-table manually, because I have an old version and can't update to latest version.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but does not address exactly my issue. I checked on ng-table website and on their website they have the exact same issue if you access it with IE. I also tried to change the source code about the default value for select filters, but in IE it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Thats true, it doesn't on IE :(

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? I have the same issue in Safari too