# Why ngModel adds a blank/empty option to a select?

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I use the `name` attribute and the `ngModel` directive as an easy way to get form values in an Angular 2 app:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" ngModel>
```

But I'm having a problem when using this approach in a `select`:

```
<select name="gender" ngModel>
```

The select with a `ngModel` renders with a blank/empty option.

Without `ngModel`:

[image]

With `ngModel`:

[image]

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hwF2U7WHp1U8IQnVGEXv?p=preview

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: That's not an empty option added, just the default value not matching any option. What do you add `ngModel` for anyway?

Comment: With NgModel, its empty because its bind to your model value. if you want any gender to be selected by default then set the gender value to your model. e,.g. [(ngModel)]="Model.value" two way binding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does angularjs include an empty option in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
<select name="gender" [(ngModel)]="gender">
```

with

```
gender: string = 'male';
```

You get the desired result. If you use `ngModel` this way, you also shouldn't need the `getFormData` method.

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SHLTMZi7eFe4IFwcqZPL?p=preview)