# Pre-select first item in sorted drop-down menu with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down-menu as follows:

```
<select ng-model="myDropDown"
        ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in myUnsortedList | orderBy:'name'"></select>
```

It is populated with an unsorted list (with member objects having `id` and `name` properties) sorted with respect to the `name` property.

An annoying problem is that AngularJS puts an empty option at the top (depicted to the left).

[image]

As [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select) the solution is to initialize the list in the controller code:

```
$scope.myDropDown = myUnsortedList[0].id;
                                   ^
                                   |
                                   +----- Index 0 selected just to take
                                          an index that always is available
```

This removes the empty item but has the side effect of making an arbitrary element the pre-selected item in the drop-down menu (right image), since `myUnsortedList` is unsorted and not in the same order as the sorted list set in `ng-options`; hence any element could have index 0 in the unsorted list.

*I would like AngularJS to not pre-select an arbitrary element in the sorted menu (i.e. select the first item instead), while avoiding the empty element. How can this be done easily?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An annoying problem is that AngularJS puts an empty option at the top.
>   solution is to initialize the list in the controller code.

Alternative solution to this, you can put placeholder instead,

```
<select ng-model="myDropDown" ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in myUnsortedList | orderBy:'name'">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
</select>
```

> side effect of making an arbitrary element the pre-selected item in
>   the drop-down menu (right image), since myUnsortedList is unsorted and
>   not in the same order

```
$scope.mySortedList = $filter('orderBy')($scope.myUnsortedList,'name');//don't forget to inject $filter in your controller
$scope.selected = 2;
```

markup:

```
ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in mySortedList"
```