# how to use ng-init with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-value

I am creating a web app in which i am using dropdown and angularjs for updating my database,

this is my syntax of my dropdownlist

```
<select ng-model="ucomname" ng-change="uucomname(o)">
       <option ng-repeat="o in comnamelistfun" value="{{o.comname}}">{{o.comname}}</option>
</select>
```

first value in this dropdown is coming blank but i want the first value of my dropdown to be the first value of my dropdown, when i used ng-init i am not able to send the value in ng-model any idea?

Comment: That's the problem when we use ng-repeat with option. I had the same issue but could not get a workaround.

Comment: Did you try to set value to `ucomname` after `comnamelistfun` are assigned to controller?

Comment: <select class="form-control"  ng-model="selectedroom" ng-options="class.Name for class in classrooms" ng-change="LoadTimeSheet(selectedroom.Id)" >
                    <option value="">Select Classroom</option>
                </select>

Comment: You can use ng-options. Follow this link it should help [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)

Answer (score 1):

First in your Controller,

```
app.controller('cardController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
    $scope.ucomname = $scope.comnamelistfun[0]
}])
```

Then the select box is,

```
<select ng-model="ucomname" ng-change="uucomname(o)" ng-options="o for o in comnamelistfun">
</select>
```

This shld work for you.

Comment: use  `$scope.comnamelistfun[0]` instead of `comnamelistfun[0]`

Comment: `               function($scope) {
                    $scope.ucomname = $scope.comnamelistfun[0]
                }`

and i also tried this

`               (function($scope) {
                    $scope.ucomname = $scope.comnamelistfun[0]
                })`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126068/discussion-between-sravan-and-ibrahim-shaikh).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.
    http://plnkr.co/edit/1EVs7R20pCffewrG0EmI?p=preview

```
    (function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('HomeCtrl', HomeCtrl);

  HomeCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function HomeCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.cities = [
      { id: 1, name: 'London' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Chicago' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Moscow' },
      { id: 4, name: 'Mumbai' },
      { id: 5, name: 'Casablanca' }
      ];

    // Pre-select city by id
    $scope.selectedCityId = 1;

    // Pre-select city by object
    $scope.selectedCity = { id: 1, name: 'Casablanca' };

  }
})();

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
  <h3>Data List</h3>

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="city in cities">
        <td>{{city.id}}</td>
        <td>{{city.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <h3>Selected City (by Id)</h3>
  selectedCityId: <strong>{{selectedCityId}}</strong>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label>Select City
    <select ng-model="selectedCityId" ng-options="city.id as city.name for city in cities">
      <option value="">-- Select City --</option>
    </select>
  </label>

  <hr/>

  <h3>Selected City (by object)</h3>
  selectedCity: <strong>{{selectedCity}}</strong>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label>Select City
    <select ng-model="selectedCity" ng-options="city as city.name for city in cities track by city.id">
      <option value="">-- Select City --</option>
    </select>
  </label>

  <hr/>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.6" data-semver="1.5.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="HomeCtrl.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<select ng-model="ucomname" ng-options= "o.comname for o in comnamelistfun track by o.comname">
</select>
```

and in your controller. Put this.

```
$scope.ucomname = $scope.comnamelistfun[0]; //This will select the first element.
```

I hope it should work :)