# Extra blank space is including in dynamic dropdown in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options, ng-init

I am creating a web app in which i am fetching the data from database,

```
<select ng-model="ucomname" ng-init="ucomname='{{o.comname}}'" ng-change="uucomname(o)">
 <option ng-repeat="o in comnamelistfun" value="{{o.comname}}">{{o.comname}}</option>
</select>
```

this is my dropdownlist, but it is adding a blank row on the top, but when i fetch static data it works fine, but when i use dynamic data it starts to add an extra blank space in the dropdownlist,

NOTE: data is pure dynamic, and it is working fine with static data

I also tried `ng-option` but still getting extra blank space

Comment: You could just add an empty option tag.

Comment: Review this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens when `ng-model` of select is undefined or value referenced by ng-model doesn't exist in a set of options. Angular adds it by default in this case. Just give some value according to your logic and it wont show blank option.

And here in `ng-init="ucomname='{{o.comname}}'"` I dont think `o` has any value since you are creating it in `ng-repeat` inside the `select` on `option` tag not on the `select` tag itself(it correct to ng-repeat the option but you cant get that variable on select)

EDIT:

I have added a example. I don't know your exact variables so used one of my choice and hence modified the ng-option declaration a little and removed the `change` function since I don't have that. But the main line below you should notice that `$scope.ucomname = $scope.comnamelistfun[0].comname;` where we are assigning a default value for `ng-model` of select.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.comnamelistfun = [
      {comname: 'a'},
      {comname: 'b'},
      {comname: 'c'}
    ];
    $scope.ucomname = $scope.comnamelistfun[0].comname;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">


<select ng-model="ucomname" ng-options="o.comname as o.comname for o in comnamelistfun">
</select>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your controller

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
$scope.comnamelistfun = [
  {comname: 'One'},
  {comname: 'Two'},
  {comname: 'Three'}
];
 $scope.ucomname=$scope.comnamelistfun[0].comname;
});
```

View

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<select ng-model="ucomname" ng-options="o.comname as o.comname for o in comnamelistfun">
```