# Remove empty option value from angular js selectbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular js for displaying dynamic option value in selectbox.
  One issue i am facing is by default it is appending one empty option to the 
  select box. Below is the selectbox code.

```
                      <select class='flowprovetermin' ng-change='gradeReloadData()' data-ng-model="provetermin[0]">
            {loop="$proveterminOptions"}
            <option value="{$value['proevetermin']}">{$value['proevetermin']}</option>
            {/loop}
           </select>
```

Please any one let me know how to remove the default empty value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)

Answer (score 0):

Look into using `ng-options` to set the `<select>` options.

**Example (HTML):**

```
<select class='flowprovetermin' 
        ng-change='gradeReloadData()' 
        ng-model="mySelectedOption"
        ng-options="myOptions">
</select>
```

**Example (JS):**

```
$scope.myOptions = [
    { id: "option1", name: "Option 1" },
    { id: "option2", name: "Option 2" },
    { id: "option3", name: "Option 3" }
];
```

**Note:**

It looks like you're assigning `ng-model` to an object in an array.
This object should probably be assigned to a variable. 
`ng-model` on your `<select>` box is the selected option.