# How to select first item as default in Angular JS dropdown?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use a dropdown, but I'm not able to select 1st value as selected by default. It showing blank.
master_data.sch_files has 4 items, but it shows 5 in dropdown in which 1st time is blank.

```
<select ng-init="item.file_range_unit = master_data.sch_files[0].ref_key" ng-model="item.file_range_unit"
                        ng-options="x.ref_key as x.ref_value for x in master_data.sch_files" required style="height: 33px;
                       width: 140px; padding-left:5px">
                  </select>
```

Comment: did my answer work?

Comment: @hasan yes, it worked

Comment: @aditya posted the answer first and u just copied the same answer from the link

Comment: @hasan for your reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/12654812/6527049

Comment: yes it is true, i have used js fiddle reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: [Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select/12654812#12654812)

> The empty option is generated when a value referenced by ng-model doesn't exist in a set of options passed to ng-options. This happens to prevent accidental model selection: AngularJS can see that the initial model is either undefined or not in the set of options and don't want to decide model value on its own.

In short: the empty option means that no valid model is selected (by valid I mean: from the set of options). You need to select a valid model value to get rid of this empty option.

All you need to do is to give a default value to:

```
item.file_range_unit
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this  `$scope.form = {type : $scope.typeOptions[0].value};` to select first element of option data.

Also this works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MTfRD/3/)

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

    // your option data
    $scope.typeOptions = [
       { name: 'Feature', value: 'feature' }, 
       { name: 'Bug', value: 'bug' }, 
       { name: 'Enhancement', value: 'enhancement' }
    ];

    $scope.form = {type : $scope.typeOptions[0].value};
}
```