# What's making a blank option appear in this code?

Tags: angularjs

I can't seem to make that blank option disappear. Any recommendation on how to do it? AngularJS is not giving me any helpful information and I tried to apply a lot of suggestions from Stackoverflow.

```js
angular.module("myApp", []);

angular.module("myApp").component("app", {
  template: `
    <div>
      <select
        ng-model="$ctrl.foo"
        ng-options="day.value as day.label for day in $ctrl.days track by day.value"
      ></select>
    </div>
  `,
  controller: function() {
    this.days = _.range(0, 31).map(function(day) {
      if (day === 0) return {label: "No Wait", value: day};
      return {label: "" + day, value: day};
    });
    this.foo = 2;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <app></app>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't think you can get rid of it, see [Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)

Comment: Change ```this.foo = 2;``` to the object ```this.foo = { value: 2 };```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)

Comment: Hey @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I know it could be a duplicate. However after applying all the suggestions in that answer, I still face the same problem. I believe is something specific to my code at this point, so I wanted to make a separate question

Answer (score 0):

Change `this.foo = 2;` to the object assignment `this.foo = { value: 2 };`

Comment: `day.value as ...` is used in `ng-options` so assigning the value directly should work.

Comment: Yeah I can confirm,  `day.value` should work perfectly, I don't want the whole object back, only the values.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like removing the `track by` part will solve this issue

```
ng-options="day.value as day.label for day in $ctrl.days"
```

Comment: But this will force the `$$hashKey` presence on all my objects, and I really don't need it since all objects are unique based on `day.value`

Comment: There is a specific section in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-) about this, maybe there can be some way to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. I can't get `ng-options` to work properly, but `ng-repeat` on `option` with `ng-value` did the trick:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []);

angular.module("myApp").component("app", {
  template: `
    <div>
      <select
        ng-model="$ctrl.foo"
      >
        <option
          ng-repeat="day in $ctrl.days track by day.value"
          ng-value="day.value"
        >
          {{day.label}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  `,
  controller: function() {
    this.days = _.range(0, 31).map(function(day) {
      if (day === 0) return {label: "No Wait", value: day};
      return {label: "" + day, value: day};
    });
    this.foo = 2;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <app></app>
</body>
```