# how to put first option of a dropdown like 'select an option'

Tags: angularjs

Initially my dropdown has a blank option by default, I would like to change the text of this option. how can I do it?

```
<body ng-controller="controller">
  <span>Options: </span>
  <select ng-options="item as item.name for item in regions track by item.code" ng-model="select">
  </select>
</body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/jEbxk4swidVenhKqZAFP?p=preview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)

Comment: @Claies sorry I updated the code..

Comment: @Claies I just need the blank text of the first dropdown option to be changed to 'select an option please'

Comment: sorry I misread the question, you aren't trying to set a default value, you are trying to make it so that the "empty" value isn't blank, which makes the proposed answer correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <select ng-options="item as item.name for item in regions track by item.code" ng-model="select">
      <option value="">Text Goes Here</option>
    </select>
```

You can also hide that option once something's chosen by using

```
<option ng-if="!select" value="">Text Goes Here</option>
```