# Setting select default value to empty on ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have this select which i need     the default value to be empty, tried adding a option with value="?" and selected="selected" but it wont work, any ideas?

```
<select class="form-control" 
        id="Select7" 
        name="grossweightmeasurementunitcode" 
        ng-model="itemForm.grossweightmeasurementunitcode" 
        ng-required="true">
        <option ng-repeat="unidadepeso in unidadespeso" value="{{unidadepeso.commoncode}}">{{unidadepeso.sigla}}</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: i think angularjs provides a blank value by default. refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<select 
                        class="form-control" 
                        id="Select7" 
                        name="grossweightmeasurementunitcode" 
                        ng-model="itemForm.grossweightmeasurementunitcode" 
                        ng-required="true">
<option value="">--Select--</opton>
                            <option ng-repeat="unidadepeso in unidadespeso" value="{{unidadepeso.commoncode}}">{{unidadepeso.sigla}}</option>
                    </select>
```