# ng-options is hiding the blank value with AngularJS V1.5

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-options

I followed the instructions specified [in the V1.3 documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/directive/select) to have a default option in one of my selects.

Therefore in my Angular ̶1̶.̶3̶.̶1̶5̶   1.5.7 template I have:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <select ng-model="selectedObj" class="form-control"
              ng-options="obj.id as obj.name for obj in objects">
        <option value="">All objects</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and in my controller I initialise it with:

```
$scope.selectedObj = '';
$scope.objects = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'A',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'B',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    name: 'C',
  },
];
```

What happens is that the "All objects" option is not shown and instead the default "blank option" is shown and is only selectable the first time. The blank option is probably the one [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select).

How can I make *my* default option work in place of the default one? What am I missing?

---

I've just found out the Angular version inside `bower_components/angular/.bower.json` is specified as `1.5.7` as opposed to what the main `bower.json` file specifies (which is 1.3.15).

May this be the cause for the seemingly weird behaviour?

Comment: Maybe the version is the problem. Because your example works for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/HogjHUQabrytcfFBYdmg?p=preview

Comment: try initialising it as `$scope.selectedObj = null;`

Comment: @SehaxX Weirdly enough the 1.5.7 [also seems to work](http://plnkr.co/edit/WjoR8kNqSbeBf8zNdkkX?p=preview). Hmm.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Tried, nothing changes.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changes. @KrupeshKotecha

Comment: @ShoeDiamente have you other code in your controller that could break it. or do you override the selectedObj or so.

Comment: @SehaxX The code I've pasted in the question is one that I've created ad-hoc for testing therefore no. Nothing changes `selectedObj` nor `objects` in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your controller.

Don't initialize your `$scope.selectedObj`.

**Updated controller:**

```
$scope.objects = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'A',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'B',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    name: 'C',
  },
];
```

**Here is a working example:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-twzxrk?file=home%2Fhome.html

Comment: As identified [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51211056/ng-options-is-hinding-the-blank-value#comment89403053_51211056) the version posted by me should work *with or without* `selectedObj`'s initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Set the ng-model to `null`:

```
 ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶O̶b̶j̶ ̶=̶ ̶'̶'̶;̶
 $scope.selectedObj = null;
```

The `ng-option` directive was heavily refactored in V1.4 and many bugs removed in V1.5. For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.4 - ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#ngoptions)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.5 - directives ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#directives-ngoptions-)

### The DEMO

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope) {
    $scope.selectedObj = null;
    $scope.objects = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'A',
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        name: 'B',
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        name: 'C',
      },
    ];
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
     <select ng-model="selectedObj" class="form-control"
             ng-options="obj.id as obj.name for obj in objects">
        <option value="">All objects</option>
     </select>
</body>
```