# how to bind default value to select using ng-model using AngularJS V1.6

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-1.6

```
<select ng-model="machineSelected"
        ng-options="machine._id as machine.name for machine in machineList"
        ng-change="onChangeMachine(machineSelected)"
        ng-disabled="!mineSelected">
    <!--<option value=""></option>-->
    <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

When I add

```
$scope.machineSelected = "";
```

dynamically wherever in the controller, option in drop-down should set as "Select", but it is not updating.

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem

Comment: what's the default value? Would `$scope.machineSelected = machineList[0]._id;` work?

Comment: When i add $scope.machineSelected = " " ,  dynamically whereever in the controller, option in dropdown should set as Select , but it is not updating.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey ---   'Select' is not available in machinelist , so machineList[0]._id contains random id number but not 'Select' ...  How to handle in these situation

Answer (score 1):

Use `null` or `undefined`, not an empty string, as the "not selected" value.

That's what the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#overview) say:

> Optionally, a single hard-coded `<option>` element, with the value set to an empty string, can be nested into the `<select>` element. This element will then represent the `null` or "not selected" option. See example below for demonstration.

It's not really clear that an empty string can't be used, but at least they mention `null`.

Comment: The `ng-options` directive was re-factored with AngularJS V1.6. Before then the default could be selected with an empty string. Now the default is selected by assigning `null` to the model.

Comment: @georgeawg Tried it ([plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/V93Ex4Rn60snX3eUWxMh?p=preview)) with different old versions. You're right. It's been changed in 1.6.5.

Answer (score 0):

Set default option in controller  and dynamically change based on selected item

```
 <select ng-model="selectedItem"  ng-change="getSelectedText()">
    <option >All Items</option>
    <option >Active Subscriptions Only</option>
    <option >Expired Only</option>
 </select>
```

Controller

```
app.controller('SelectedTextController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.selectedItem = "All Items";
    $scope.getSelectedText = function () {
        var selectedItem=this.selectedItem;
    };       
});
```

Comment: Pls accept and upvote it  if you found the answer helpful

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to upvote , although i upvoted

Answer (score 0):

Use `null` for the unselected value:

```
̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶m̶a̶c̶h̶i̶n̶e̶S̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶=̶ ̶"̶"̶;̶
$scope.machineSelected = null;
```

The `ng-options` directive was re-factored with AngularJS V1.6. Before then the default could be selected with an empty string. Now the default is selected by assigning `null` to the model.

For more infomation, see

- [AngularJS API Reference - Using `select` with `ngOptions` and setting a default value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-select-with-ngoptions-and-setting-a-default-value)
- [AngularJS ng-options Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#overview)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.6 - select directve](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ng-directives-select)
- [ng-options is hiding the blank value with AngularJS V1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51211056/ng-options-is-hiding-the-blank-value-with-angularjs-v1-5/51212295#51212295)

### [The DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/xoMkQkxrxBAIJFirktOh?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
  $scope.machineList = [
    { _id:1, name: "Megatron" },
    { _id:2, name: "Starscream" },
    { _id:3, name: "Shockwave" },
  ];
  $scope.machineSelected = null;
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script> 
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <select ng-model="machineSelected"
        ng-options="machine._id as machine.name for machine in machineList"
        ng-change="onChangeMachine(machineSelected)">
       <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    machineSelected={{machineSelected}}
</body>
```