# How to remove empty entry from ng-repeat Angulst JS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi This is my html code

```
 <select style="width: 199px;margin-top: -9px;" id="ddlTypeCode" ng-model="selectedCountryCode" ng-change="locationChange(selectedCountryCode)" name="ddlTypeCode" class="form-control">
                    <option ng-repeat="Country in CountryList track by $index" value="{{Country}}"
                            ng-selected="Country == 'India'">
                        {{Country}}
                    </option>
```

CountryList  don't have any empty value but in UI Drop down showing one empty entry.Please suggests

Answer (score 1):

Its a common thing in angularjs when using arrays with `ng-repeat`.

Its simple, just add an `<option>` tag with `style="display:none"` 
i.e `<option style="display:none"></option>`
It does the job.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
 $scope.CountryList = ["India", "China", "Japan"]; 
   
   
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    
<select style="width: 199px;margin-top: -9px;" id="ddlTypeCode" ng-model="selectedCountryCode" ng-change="locationChange(selectedCountryCode)" name="ddlTypeCode" class="form-control">
          <option  style="display:none;"></option>
         <option ng-repeat="Country in CountryList " value="{{Country}}"ng-selected="Country == 'India'">
                        {{Country}}
                    </option>
        

</div>
```

Hope it helps..
Cheers!

~ NiKhIl

Comment: `track by $index`  is used if there are any duplicate entries, there's no need here I guess.

Answer (score -1):

The empty option is generated when a value referenced by ng-model doesn't exist in a set of options passed to ng-options.

have a look at [Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)

Comment: @Adriani6 why down vote ? becuase lack of reputation cant comment. i post answer faster then you

Comment: You can't just post this as an answer. The board will be a mess if everyone does. When you have enough rep you can then post comments. The system was designed this way and you should accept and follow that. You don't have to use comments. At 15 reputation, you'll see a 'flag' option which we use to flag questions as duplicates to also keep the forums nicely organised and tidy. It all comes with patience :)

Comment: if i cant post comment how does i gain reputation ?

Comment: By answering questions you can in the mean time. I know it sounds hard but we all had to start at the same place :)

Comment: ok understood now