# html select element with default not in the options

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [<select> placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/select-placeholder)

I want to do something like this:

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected">Choose option</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

here's the [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/yahyaKACEM/QnAKU/)

now I want the first option the selected one with the content "Choose option" to not be visible in the dropdown. how can i do that, if that's possible with a select element or should i do a custom thing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, if you don't wnt it to appear, why not just remove it?

Comment: because i want it to be there at the first load of the page i don't want to select the first option by default.

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig, and you think that question is the same here, because?!?!

Comment: As far as I am aware selected="selected" is not completely valid. Since the selected attribute on its own is a boolean statement in an option statement, it’s presence alone states true, or absence false.
Here’s the w3c’s example page based on the spec:
http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/option

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could remove the selected element as soon as you open the list:

```
$('select').click(function () {
  $('option[selected="selected"]', this).remove();
});
```

I am not aware of any native HTML/HTML5 solution.

Comment: that will only remove the selected item after i choose an option not when i click to open the drop down, chack my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yahyaKACEM/QnAKU/1/)

Comment: Hmm... works fine for me. Which browser do you use?

Comment: did the selected option gets removed when you click to open the dropdown.

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and even IE.

Comment: actually it worked fine on firefox but chrome still don't work for me.

Answer (score 18):

I believe the closest you can get with a plain HTML-solution is to disable that option:

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Choose option</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wYgQW/)

The element will still appear in the the list, but it will be grayed out and it will not be possible to select it from the dropdown after opening it.

Comment: yes, i know that solution i was hoping for another one. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Choose option</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

This will show "choose option" before selecting, but will not allow the user to select it.