# how to set a default prompt when nothing selected for "select" using css

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set a default prompt when nothing is selected for select box using css? or is there an elegant way to deal with this other than

```
 <option>Select Here</option>?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a placeholder for a 'select' box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled>Select one--</option>
    <option value="someVal1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="someVal2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="someVal3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="someVal4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Note: I deleted my previous answer as @Quentin pointed out that I was mistaken about `<options>` and I found other sources to refute my statement that it is not an element. However, I did find out that the inconsistent support across browsers (as alluded to by @Quentin) and the fact that they can only exist within `<select>` elements has led many to *consider* them to be more like attributes, than elements, in order to keep things compatible and follow best practices.

Comment: not bad at all... although i was hoping some kind of placeholder similar to input text.. but still helpful. thanks

Comment: No worries - sorry about the confusion :)

Comment: "the fact that they can only exist within `<select>` elements has led many to consider them to be more like attributes, than elements, in order to keep things compatible and follow best practices". How you *think* about the `<option>` element doesn't affect how compatible your code is, and "best practices" is a bit of a meaningless phrase.

Comment: also, you can add `selected="selected"` to have it be the default value as well.  If the value gets changed, it won't be able to change back

Comment: ``disabled`` [does not allow for validation to occur](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532482/html5-form-validation-with-required-and-disabled-element), and keeps the ``select`` *valid*.  This answer is partially incorrect.  Edited answer.

Comment: this is useless, the initial prompt is not selected on load

Comment: @SuperUberDuper the OP specifically asked for how to set a default prompt when nothing is selected on load. This solution leverages default browser functionality that displays the text of the first option when none have been selected. Since it is a default value, I inferred that the value should not be selected by default. If you want it selected then combine it with the comment by cadlac and enjoy. To simply call the solution "useless" is incorrect, crass and frankly a bit rude.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I didn't see cadlacs answer. +1

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer did not work for me as expected.

If you need the "Select one option" to be the selected one by default , this worked for me

```
<select id="selected_option" name="selected_option">
     <option value="default" selected="selected">Select one option </option>
     <option value="someVal1">Option 1</option>
     <option value="someVal2">Option 2</option>
     <option value="someVal3">Option 3</option>
     <option value="someVal4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Is also important that the **select** has **id** and **name** so when you submit the form the value will be part of the POST or GET

Comment: It doesn't need id, name is enough.

Comment: id is required if one uses `<label for="selected_option">Label Text</label>`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it worked as it should for me

Comment: select is such a broken component

Comment: how would you html5 validation force the select to have non default?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper sorry I did not understand. What do you mean or trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 4):

```html
                        <select>
                            <option style="display:none">Empty</option>
                            <option>button1</option>
                            <option>button2</option>
                        </select>
```

Comment: This combined with disabled is perfect

Comment: But we have nothing to do with it, if we want to choose prompt option back manually.

Answer (score 3):

Try using option with unset value

```
<select>    
    <option value>Select something</option>
    <option value="1">Foo</option>
    <option value="2">Bar</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, as it doesn't display "Select something". The default selected option is an empty text one

Comment: Simple solution to **@Bogdan's** problem is to set placeholder for select tag.`<select placeholder="Select something."></select>`

Answer (score 3):

This is how I use for setup the default prompt but it will not set a default value. It use a HTML5 validation `required`. It may be a little bit shift from the question but I hope it could help as alternative.

```
<select id="car" name="car[brand]" required>
  <option disabled selected>Select Car Brand</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```