# How to create a <select> placeholder

Tags: jquery, html, select, placeholder

In my select elements, I want a default text such as "please select an option". Also I use the jQuery plugin [Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) with my form so that the user cannot submit the form if he has not selected something in my select elements.

Problem is, if I have "please select an option" in my selects, the form will validate.

How to deal with this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [<select> placeholder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/select-placeholder)

Comment: remove value attr from that option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<select>
    <option value="">Please select an option</option>
```

`<option>` content is only used when the `value` is not empty.

http://jsfiddle.net/s5AVg/

Comment: It is not selected by default.. Even if I do <option selected value="">Please select an option</option>

Answer (score 4):

```
<select>
    <option style="display:none">please select an option</option>
    <option disabled="disabled">I am a line</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```