# How to make placeholder in semantic-ui?

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-select, semantic-ui

I am using https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html plugin and I have to display the placeholder. I am retrieving data from the database which is working but the placeholder is not displaying.

Note:- If I remove PHP code than it is displaying placeholder.

I tried

```
$('select.dropdown').dropdown({placeholder:'select option'});
```

and also tried

```
<option value="" selected="selected" disabled >Select option</option>
```

but not working. Please check my code and assist me.

```
    <select  class="ui fluid search dropdown" id='select-super'>
   <option value="">Select Option</option>

      <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($learn_teach_result)):;?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>"><?php echo $row['email'];?></option>
                <?php endwhile;?> 
    </select>
```

Comment: Duplicate? [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222655/how-to-create-a-select-placeholder)

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.maximelian, I know how to use placeholder in HTML, and I also added tried code but that is not working.

Comment: I found my solution now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did. I add placeholder inside While. I don't know it is right or wrong but working for me.

Thanks, MR.Gibbok, With the help of your comment I got my solution

```
<select  class="ui fluid search dropdown" id='select-super'>
  <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($learn_teach_result)):;?>
   <option value="">Select Option</option>
   <option value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>"><?php echo $row['email'];?></option>
    <?php endwhile;?> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an option with no value, this data should be present in your array in the PHP.

Example:

```
<div class="another dropdown example">
  <select class="ui dropdown">
    <option value="">Gender</option> <!-- your placeholder -->
    <option value="1">Male</option>
    <option value="0">Female</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not working. I tried I am retrieving data form database.

Comment: @NarendraVerma your issue is in the PHP, you should add your placeholder in the array in your PHP value assigning a value an empty string

Comment: I think this is a common solution. I use it usually.

Comment: I found my solution now

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
<select  class="ui fluid search dropdown" id='select-super'>
   <option value="">Select Option</option>
  <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($learn_teach_result)):;?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>"><?php echo $row['email'];?></option>
        <?php endwhile;?> 
</select>
```