# How to add default text to HTML <select>?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to add some default text to a HTML `select` box. The `placeholder` tag which works with `input` doesn't seam to work whit this one?

This works

```
<td><input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $lang ['your_website']; ?>"/></td>
```

This doesn't work

```
<td><select type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $lang ['select']; ?>"/></td>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You provide a set of options for the select and one of them must be selected.

Comment: You appear to be abusing `placeholder` as if it were a `<label>`. Don't do that, it causes accessibility problems.

Comment: You may want to try this: [<select> placeholder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/select-placeholder).

Comment: The `placeholder` attribute does not set default text in `input`. It sets a placeholder. The `value` attribute sets the default value of the control. You need to define what you really want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you looking for the `selected` attribute?

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected">Select Country</option>
    <option>United States</option>
    <option>Mexico</option>
</select>
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Comment: You beat me to it by 13 seconds! +1

Comment: @Louis Thanks for the answer, but **NO** I'm not looking for that! I just want to have a ´default text´ such as "optional" or "select country" in the text box. As mentioned ´placeholder ´works fine with the ´input´ box but for some reason doesn't work with the ´select´ box.

Comment: I fear you have fundamentally misunderstood your problem, and as a consequence fail to see the correctness of both @RahulTripathi and my answers.

Comment: @Louis I was looking for a simple way to add a text inside the text box. It's suppose to be something like **please select** or **optional**. It will disappear once the user starts to type in something. Placeholder is something I found during my research - I never used it before and it worked. But as you can see from my question, I wasn't insisting on that. But I still didn't understand how to solve my problem with the way you showed. How can I implement this?

Comment: @Teo you don't type in a select field, so your question doesn't make sense. Are you thinking of something like this: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ ?

Comment: @Louise Sorry for the confusion, I mean **select** not type. Additional to this, I finally understood what you mean and you're right, this is the solution for my problem. Somehow I was so focused on the solution with placeholder in combination with the **input** box. That I didn't see the difference of both issues. So thanks for pointing it out! +1 for your efforts!

Comment: +1 for pointing out the correct approach instead of blatantly stating "It's not possible" and for the reference :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use it like this:

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected">Default Option</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

ie, use `selected="selected"` for the option you want to be the default.

or you may try this:

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Default Option</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```