# Changing color of placeholder in dropdown

Tags: html, css

You can see the form I'm working on here:

`http://www.escalateinternet.com/free-quote.php`

This is the code for the drop down budget:

```
            <td><select id="budget" style="width:420px;">
                <option value="">Choose Your Budget</option>
                <option value="250">$250-$500 Per Month</option>
                <option value="500">$500-$750 Per Month</option>
                <option value="750">$750-$1000 Per Month</option>
                <option value="100">$1000-$1500 Per Month</option>
                <option value="1500">$1500-$2500 Per Month</option>
                <option value="2500">$2500-$5000 Per Month</option>
                <option value="5000">$5000-$7500 Per Month</option>
                <option value="7500">$7500-$10000 Per Month</option>
                <option value="10000">$10,000 or More Per Month</option>
            </select></td>
```

How can I make it so that "Choose Your Budget" is the same gray colored text as the rest of the placeholders are by default and then when a budget is selected that text is the darker color.  I'm just trying to basically make it match the color scheme the rest of the form is using...

Answer (score -4, accepted):

> ## Notice:
>
> After more than **six years** of the answer, in some browsers, this snippet is no longer run as expected. For example, in current
> FireFox versions. However, in Opera 70.0.3728.95, it still works.

You can use pseudo class `option:checked`

```
<style>
    #budget option:checked{
      color:red;
    }
  </style>
```

look at this demo: http://jsbin.com/gilip/1

Comment: Where are you seeing red in your demo?

Comment: Click the dropdown and select a value, then click it again and you will see the previous selected item in red color.

Comment: I don't know why down vote?! The demo is working fine, and the op set it to be correct answer?!

Comment: I think because the original question was talking about `placeholder` color value. Like when you have `input:text` field and you set the placeholder color

Answer (score 10):

Possible duplicate of [How do I make a placeholder for a 'select' box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/select-placeholder)

The short of it is, `select` elements don't support placeholders and what you want to do isn't quite achievable in css. However; some simple JS can help us here.

(I'm assuming you'll using jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').on('change', function(){ //attach event handler to select's change event. 
                                        //use a more specific selector

        if ($(this).val() === ""){ //checking to see which option has been picked

            $(this).addClass('unselected'); 
        } else {                   // add or remove class accordingly
            $(this).removeClass('unselected');
        }

    });
});
```

Bonus edit: the if/else block can be refactored into one line (see [jquery `.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)) :

```
$(this).toggleClass('unselected', $(this).val() === "");
```

I'd also advise giving it the `disabled` attribute. You can then add styles like this:

```
select{
    color: black;
}
select.unselected{
    color: gray;
}
//edit: you might want to do this to make it that bit nicer:
select option:first-child{
    display: none;
}
```

don't forget to give the `select` element an initial class of `unselected`.

hope this helps!

Comment: -1 for Javascript when there is no JS tag and jQuery when there is no jQ tag.

Comment: How is the asker supposed to know he should tag JavaScript when he doesn't know that he will need to use JavaScript?

Comment: Furthermore, there was no possible solution using HTML or CSS, as I explained at the beginning of my answer, and so I offered a possible solution using JavaScript. @bjb568

Comment: I have been looking for a way to do this in CSS for awhile. I have resorted to javascript and this seems the best solution. @Billy I'd like to amend, `if ($(this).val() == "0")` to `if ($(this).val() == "")` and `<option value="">` so you can `<select required="">`. Value has to be empty for required to work.

Comment: Thanks @BradleyForster I have edited your suggestion into the answer (Along with another small improvement).

Comment: This helped me a lot, I place the class "unselected" on my <select> from the begininng (to change the color) and when the user selects an option it changes to the color I want so this is really working, thanks

Comment: Added a pure JavaScript way in the comments. Not sure if it is still relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I did it with the placeholder text color being light gray, normal text white, and background black.  The selected option will still be white after focus is moved away.

```
select {
    color: #fff!important;
    background-color: #000!important;
}
select:invalid {
    color: #535353!important;
}
select:focus {
    color: #fff!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way of doing this without using jQuery.

```
    select {
            color: #aaa; /* default unselected color */
    }

    select:focus {
            color: red; /* color when focused */
    }

    #budget option:checked{
            color: red; /* color when selected but not focused */
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the dropdown is a *required* field, you can use the `:invalid` pseudo-class. [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid):

> The `:invalid` CSS pseudo-class represents any `<input>` or other `<form>` element whose contents fail to validate.

This means that when the selected option's value is blank (i.e. `value=""`), the `:invalid` pseudo-class selector will be active on the `<select>` element because a value is required. See my example below:

```css
/* 1 - Disable default browser styling */
select {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

/* 2 - Style default state using the :invalid pseudo-class */
select:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select name="color" required>
  <option value="" selected>Select a size</option>
  <option value="sm">Small</option>
  <option value="md">Medium</option>
  <option value="lg">Large</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure JavaScript way (based on Bill's answer), as there is **still no pure html/css way to do this** (that I know of).

EDIT: You could set the disabled property on the placeholder option but this is not supported by all browsers AND you can't style the select based on the options attributes.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('select'), function(currentSelect) {
  // Trigger placeholder method for the first time
  updatePlaceholder(currentSelect);

  // Bind change event to every select that is found on the page. 
  currentSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
    updatePlaceholder(this);
  });

});


function updatePlaceholder(select) {
  select.classList.toggle('unselected', !select[select.selectedIndex].value);
}
```

```css
select.unselected {
  opacity: .5;
  filter: grayscale();
}
```

```html
<select id="budget" style="width:420px;">
  <option value="">Choose Your Budget</option>
  <option value="250">$250-$500 Per Month</option>
  <option value="500">$500-$750 Per Month</option>
  <option value="750">$750-$1000 Per Month</option>
  <option value="100">$1000-$1500 Per Month</option>
  <option value="1500">$1500-$2500 Per Month</option>
  <option value="2500">$2500-$5000 Per Month</option>
  <option value="5000">$5000-$7500 Per Month</option>
  <option value="7500">$7500-$10000 Per Month</option>
  <option value="10000">$10,000 or More Per Month</option>
</select>
```