# How do I set the fiirst select option to be gray even when the dropdown is closed

Tags: css

I am trying to set the color of just the first item in the dropdown to be a different color even when the dropdown is closed.

```
 <label for="labelCountry">Country</label>
      <select name="country" class="form-control" id="country" onchange="stateMenu(this.value);">
                        <option style="color:#AFBAC7 !important;" value="" selected>Select a Country</option>
                        <option value="US">United States</option>
                        <option value="CA">Canada</option>
                        <option value="In">India</option>
                        <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
                        <option value="FR">France</option>
                        <option value="CH">China</option>
                        <option value="JA">Japan</option>
                        <option value="GE">Germany</option>
                        <option value="AU">Australia</option>
                        <option value="RU">Russia</option>
                        <option value="CA">Canada</option>
                        <option value="PA">Pakistan</option>
                        <option value="IT">Italy</option>
                        <option value="SP">Spain</option>
                        <option value="SK">South Korea</option>
                        <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
                        <option value="EN">England</option>
                        <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
                        <option value="SI">Singapore</option>
                        <option value="GR">Greece</option>
                        <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
       </select>
```

Comment: You may want to change your question and add the code. A hint it to use the CSS `:first-child` selector.

Comment: The first style selector only changes the color of the first item when the drop down is open. I would like the first item color to be changed even when the drop down is closed.

Comment: Why does it matter when it is closed though if no one can see it?

Comment: When it is closed it still has the "Select a country" displayed and thats the main element I want to change the color.

Comment: You're looking for a way to style the placeholder of a select. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652680/changing-color-of-placeholder-in-dropdown) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box) for possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this without JavaScript is to make the select `required` and style it up as gray when invalid.

However, note that if no option is selected your `<form>` will not validate, so this is not good if you use it on a select that's not actually required and you need the form to validate.

```css
select:invalid, 
select option:first-child {
  color: #999;
}
select:invalid option {
  color: black;
}
select option:first-child {
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<select required>
  <option value="">Please select an option</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

---

Although I really like CSS only solutions, in this particular case it feels more correct to just use a trivial check `onchange` and set  color of the `<select>` by applying/removing a class:

```js
function onChangeHandler() {
  var select = document.getElementById('theSelect');
  select.classList[select.value === '' ? 'add':'remove']('empty');
}
```

```css
select.empty, select option:first-child {
  color: #999;
}
select, .empty option:not(:first-child) {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="onChangeHandler()" id="theSelect" class="empty">
  <option value="">Please select an option</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

---

And this would be the jQuery version:

```js
$('#theSelect')
  .on('change', function(){ 
    $(this)[
      $(this).val() === '' ? 'addClass':'removeClass'
    ]('empty');
  })
```

```css
select.empty, select option:first-child {
  color: #999;
}
select, .empty option:not(:first-child) {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="theSelect" class="empty">
  <option value="">Please select an option</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its the `disabled="disabled"` you're trying to achieve? If you add this to the first `option`, by default this changes the colour to grey.

Comment: The user wants to change the colour of the first item "Select a Country". This doesn't disable the entire select box, just this first item. The question wasn't clear as to why they want to change the colour.

Comment: Phew, I feel much better now i've had a dressing down by you, thanks.

Comment: I thought I was helping. I generally want my [so] answers to be correct and assumed the same. I do apologize.

Comment: Just a thought, since the first option was set to no value, then it's good to disable it so it looks like a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work as a pure CSS solution (although I'm not sure if you really need to add the `!important` part but that will depend on your project):

```
select:not(:-internal-list-box) {
  color: #AFBAC7 !important;
}

option {
  color: black !important;
}
```

I made a fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/rL7s1024/1/).

You can read about the `:not` css selector [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp).

Also, you may want to add additional classes to these elements to make the styling unique to this dropdown menu.

Comment: In Chrome it remains gray even when I select a proper country, Brandon.

Comment: Ahh... I understood that they wanted to keep whatever was in the input box grey.  Hmm...there must be a fix to this...

Answer (score 0):

**If I understand you correctly;this is simple via jquery . . . :D**

**1) adding this script in `document's Ready` :**

```
    $(function () {

    // first run
    $("select").each(function () {
        checkSelect($(this));
    });

    // after change
    $(document).on("change", "select", function () {
        checkSelect($(this));
    });

    function checkSelect($el) {
        $el.find("option:selected").index() == 0 ? $el.addClass("placeholder") : $el.removeClass("placeholder");
    }

})
```

**2) adding style into your page:**

```
    select.placeholder,
    select.placeholder option:first-child {
        color: #AFBAC7 !important;
    }

    select option {
        color: #333;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jj89198103/yw6xe1kv/