# How to add name/placeholder on combo box/select in html

Tags: combobox, html-select

I want to add placeholder or name on the select.. I want "Pet Type" will show up but the "Pet 1" will show..thanks..

```
<select name="Pet Type">
    <option value="A">Pet 1</option>
    <option value="B">Pet 2</option>
    <option value="C">Pet 3</option>
</select>
```

I want to add placeholder or name on the select.. I want "Pet Type" will show up but the "Pet 1" will show..thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Use `<option value="" disabled selected>-- Pet Type --</option>` as your first option, see [How do I make a placeholder for a 'select' box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/select-placeholder)