# select selected label without being an option

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Didn't how to put this question... How can I show a descrition / deafukt value without it being an options.

Eg:

```
    <select class="form-control">
            <option value="">Choose a Number...</option>
            <option value="two">Two</option>
            <option value="three">Three</option>
            <option value="four">Four</option>
            <option value="five">Five</option>
    </select>
```

How to show "Choose a Number" in unselected mode but not have it as an option. Like dropdown should show only the options which can be selected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [<select> placeholder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/select-placeholder)

Comment: You should think that after a person has selected something then they won't be able to reset the value... which sounds a bit like bad UX.

Comment: But then selecting an option is mandatory... @Daniel

Comment: @DebajyotiDas people usually use other type of user engagement, like nice UI validations (less aggressive). Use a label that says "Choose a number" and next to it render your dropdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The select tag doesn't come with a placeholder attribute. To work around that you can do the following:

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option class="hidden_option" selected disabled>Choose a number</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
select > option.hidden_option{
    display: none;
}
```

This way you can make a pseudo-placeholder that will not be listed as an option.

Here is a [JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chcpwpaq/1) for you to see it in action

Comment: This also worked... `<option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Please Choose</option>
`

Comment: well ... yeah ... that's the exact same thing ... except the example I gave you doesn't use inline css (which is recommended not to use) ...

Comment: Does bootstrap have an feature to do this by default... ?

Comment: No. At least not that I know of. But there are a gazillion of components to treat select boxes. The most popular may very well be select2.