# AngularJS - How to add placeholder text to dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I want to add a placeholder to my dropdown.
I am not hard coding my dropdown values, it's coming from some where. Can you tell me where i did mistake.

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3">Action<span style="color: #b94a48">*</span></b></label>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-7" style="padding: 0px;">
        <div class="dropdown select" style="width: 100%;">
            <select name="wlOrdActType" class="dropdown multiple" placeholder="-- Please Select --" 
                ng-model="wlOrdActType" 
                ng-options="obj.name as obj.name for obj in ordertypeList"
                style="width: 100%;">
                    <option></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here every thing is working. But placeholder is not place on the dropdown

Comment: Have you tried just putting -- Please Select -- in the empty option tag?

Comment: That is not a place holder right.It treat like a one option.

Comment: The `<select>` element does not support the `placeholder` attribute. ([ref1](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp), [ref2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select))

Comment: Select boxes don't support the placeholder attribute. The accepted answer on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/select-placeholder) will give you the best solution.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i place some text on dropdown.

Answer (score 17):

```
<option value="" disabled selected>Please Select</option>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this:

```
<select ng-model="wlOrdActType" ng-options="obj.name as obj.name for obj in ordertypeList">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Choose one</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please add more detail and explain the solution - why and how will this solve OP's problem? What technique was OP not using?

Answer (score 3):

Could also try this:

```
<select required class="form-control" ng-model="myModel" 
ng-options="item as item.title for item in list">
    <option value="" label="-- Select option --" disabled selected="selected">      
    </option>
</select>
```

While having the model set to an empty string in the controller.

```
 $scope.myModel = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Angular v1.6.6. So, check for older version's compatibility. I believe the below code should work v1.5 onwards.

```
$scope.ordertypeList = ordertypeListFromApiCall; // Get the collection from API
$scope.ordertypeList.splice(0,0, {'id' : '', 'name' : 'Select Order Type...' } );                 
$scope.wlOrdActType = $scope.ordertypeList[0];
```

And in the HTML,

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="wlOrdActType" required ng-options="ordertype.name disable when ordertype.id == '' for ordertype in ordertypeList track by ordertype.id">
</select>
```

In the itemSelected function, make sure that the id of $scope.wlOrdActType is not empty