# Select default text visible only when nothing is selected [HTML5]

Tags: html, select, text, input, box

I think this question is very easy, but I don't know it.
Do you know those text boxes in HTML5, for example password box, and it says "Write Password", but when you click on it, text disappears?
How is that called? Can it be done to select object in HTML5?

Thank you

---------EDIT-----------
I found answer right here, if someone bumps on this question:
[How do I make a placeholder for a 'select' box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `placeholder` attribute on your text boxes:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="write name" />
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

For select box take a look at this question:

[How do I make a placeholder for a 'select' box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box)