# How to disable the dropdown menu

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

Here is my code for static drop down.How to disable the dropdown or remove the option to select values

```
<?php
    $designationsOptions = array('0'=> 'Select Weekly Day Off','Sunday' => 'Sunday','Monday' => 'Monday','Tuesday' => 'Tuesday','Wednesday' => 'Wednesday','Thursday' => 'Thursday','Friday' => 'Friday','Saturday' => 'Saturday');
    $designationsOptionsJs = 'id="shiftDayOff" class="form-control shiftDayOff"';
    echo "<div class='drop_shiftDayOff'>";
    echo form_dropdown('shiftDayOff', $designationsOptions,$shifts[0]['shiftDayOff'],$designationsOptionsJs);
    echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign disabled attribute to dropdown menu in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278791/how-to-assign-disabled-attribute-to-dropdown-menu-in-codeigniter)

Comment: I tried it,But its not working  @Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following string to your $designationsOptionsJs variable:

```
$designationsOptionsJs += " disabled=disabled";
```

This should work.