# Select box styling not taking place

Tags: html, css

I created a select/option box and my styling is not taking place. I have uploaded the same files multiple times, so it is not that. I created a fiddle to see if it would work and it does. However, when I add more of my css code it goes back to an un-styled version. I do not see what I am doing wrong with the code over-top of this for it to break. Does anyone see something I am overlooking?

https://jsfiddle.net/ybd0bLr1/1/

`.selectbar` is the class in which my select bar styling comes from.

```
.inputbarphone[type=tel] {
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
.inputbarphone:hover {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
}
.inputbarphone[type=tel]:focus {
    border: 1px solid #3385FF;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(51,133,255, 1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba((51,133,255, 1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(51,133,255, 1);
}
.selectbar {
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
```

Comment: Some good reading on the subject of mucking with select box styling https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra parentheses on this line:

```
.inputbarphone[type=tel]:focus {
    border: 1px solid #3385FF;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(51,133,255, 1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba((51,133,255, 1); <-----
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(51,133,255, 1);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ybd0bLr1/2/

As @Quentin said, just do this:

```
.inputbarphone[type=tel]:focus {
    border: 1px solid #3385FF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(51,133,255, 1);
}
```

Comment: Using vendor prefixed box-shadow today is [pointless](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow) and if this error had been made on a standard property, it would have been picked up by a [validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't see that. Why is the placeholder not showing though?

Comment: @Becky regarding placeholders for select menus... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box

Comment: @Quentin agreed can't remember last time I used vendor prefix on box-shadow.

Comment: @Quentin How else would I add the box shadow then?

Comment: @Becky just drop vendor prefix and use `box-shadow`.  And don't forget to Lint your code!

Comment: @Becky what placeholder? Edit: Never mind I am blind. I would take robabby suggestion with the link.

Comment: I figured out the placeholder, except my font doesn't match. Would I just give that option a different class to match the normal shade of gray for placeholder font?

Comment: Can't say I have ever used a placeholder for select before. Update fiddle and I will take a look at font issue.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace I tried your box shadow method, but changed the color to #ccc, but it doesn't look the same as my other box shadows. It just likes like a bit of gray all around it. Can't I just delete my webkits and have the same thing?

Comment: @Becky I am not sure what you mean. Its not my method. Its just the style property name. It doesn't require vendor prefixes anymore. Every browser supports it.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace I mean can't I just do this... `/*-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;*/
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;` The areas commented out, I mean just remove those parts.

Comment: @Becky Yea. But you originally had 0 0 1px 1px. Maybe thats why you don't like the look anymore?

Comment: @Becky Linting is a practice of validating your code.  A linter would have caught your extra parentheses and thrown an error, showing you which line it failed on.  The link AtheistP3ace is a great place to start.  if you are using Atom or Sublime Text, they have some great linting plugins that will do it for you in the editor.  https://atom.io/packages/linter-csslint

Comment: Great! that will definitely come in handy! Thanks!!