# Style the first select option in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to change font color of the first select option which has Bootstrap's `form-control` class as follows:

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

I tried styling it using the `first-child` attribute as follows, but it colors everything in red:

```
select.form-control { color: red; }
select.form-control option { color: black; }
select.form-control option:first-child { color: red; }
```

I even tried styling it inline, but it is still unable to override Bootstrap's css:

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option style="color: red;" color="red">1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Interestingly, the css correctly styles the first element when it's a `multiple` style, but that's not what I need:

```
<select multiple class="form-control">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Here's a codepen reproducing this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKjYjq

**UPDATE 1:**

By first element I mean the first option within select (i.e. `<option>1</option>`). I'd like it to be red, and the rest black.

Unlike some comments reported with the original Codepen, even the inline approach doesn't work for me in Chrome 47, Safari 9 and Firefox 42 on Mac:

[image]
[image]

The desired option is where number `2` in the image above (along with other options below it) is black, but option `1` is red.

Comment: It looks to be working as you describe! what are you asking for?

Comment: Please explain to me how this is not what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/oa9wj80x/1/

Comment: yes I just change `select.form-control { color: red; }` to `select.form-control { color: blue; }` and it is working.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith maybe it's browser dependent? All the options are black when I bring that fiddle up in Safari. And Chrome. And Firefox.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Chrome for Mac 47.0.2526, and Firefox Dev edition for Mac 44.0a2.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Definitely am. Screenshots for Safari and FF, respectively: https://www.runtondev.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Safari-dropped-selected.png https://www.runtondev.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Firefox-dropped-selected.png

Comment: @Craine get a new computer lol, black and white screens are outdated...

Comment: What do you mean by the first element and what browser are you using to check that behaviour?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith what versions of FF and Chrome are you using?

Comment: I am deleting my previous comments, this is getting ridiculous

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith please see the update.

Comment: @Olga please see the update

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong you want it to be red both in "dropdown" and in "input" but only this particular option, not the other ones? And you want to accomplish this using css?

Comment: @Olga I'd like it to be red only in the "input" once selected. JS solution is fine too, but I'd prefer css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript based solution (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQpGpY)

**Markup:**

```
<select class="form-control">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>
```

**Css:**

```
select.form-control.first-option-selected {
  color: red;
}

select.form-control > option {
  color: black;
}
```

**Javascript (jQuery is used for convinience):**

```
$(function () {
  var selectElement = $('select.form-control');

  function ifFirstOptionSelectedMakeItRed() {
    if (selectElement[0].selectedIndex === 0) {
      selectElement.addClass('first-option-selected');
    } else {
      selectElement.removeClass('first-option-selected');
    }
  }

  ifFirstOptionSelectedMakeItRed();

  selectElement.on('change', function () {
    ifFirstOptionSelectedMakeItRed();
  })
});
```

My reasoning for this solution is this:

- I don't think you can check which option is selected via css. My first idea was to use attributes selector. But I couldn't find any usefull attributes in documentation for this element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select
- Nor for the option element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option
- So being a lame css'er I turned to js - and everything is pretty simple there https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement you have all sorts of properties to check against. I ended up using `selectedIndex`. And there is a `change` event for when user chooses a new option. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

Comment: Best solution, since doesn't rely on the values of options.

Answer (score 2):

This is right from your own code: https://jsfiddle.net/oa9wj80x/2/

If that is not exactly what you are asking then IDK  lol

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option style="color: red;">1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

**edit 1**

or are you looking for this effect? https://jsfiddle.net/oa9wj80x/3/

**edit2**

I think this is what you are trying to do? https://jsfiddle.net/oa9wj80x/5/

```
<select id="slct" onchange="change()" class="form-control">
  <option id="opt1" value="1">1</option>
  <option id="opt2" value="2">2</option>
  <option id="opt3" value="3">3</option>
  <option id="opt4" value="4">4</option>
  <option id="opt5" value="5">5</option>
</select>
<script>
function change(){
    var x = document.getElementById("slct").value;

  if(x > 1){
    document.getElementById("slct").style.color = "black";
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("slct").style.color = "red";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: unfortunately your solution still doesn't work on my mac in latest Chrome 47, Safari 9 and Firefox 42 on Mac. In your first jsfiddle all options render as black, and in the second jsfiddle all options are black. The desired behaviour is where only option 1 is red and rest is black. I can provide a screenshot if you'd like.

Comment: @SBBS Thanks for clarifying, i will adjust my answer now

Comment: @SBBS look at **edit 2** Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: LOL I was soo confused :) good to see we got it to work... finally

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Even inline doesn't work:</p>
<select class="form-control">
  <option style="color:red;">1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

This is works without any css changes.

Comment: unfortunately your solution doesn't work on my mac in latest Chrome 47, Safari 9 and Firefox 42 on Mac. All options render as black while the desired behaviour is where only option 1 is red and rest is black. I can provide a screenshot if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Having browsed around I found a css-only solution that works in modern browsers:

```
select:required:invalid {
  color: red;
}
option[value=""][disabled] {
  display: none;
}
option {
  color: black;
}
```

HTML

```
<select required class="form-control">
  <option value="" disabled selected>1</option>
  <option value="1">2</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
</select>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29806043