# How to make save button as disable when select dropdown value is "select"

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a form which i need to select one value and i am setting default value to the select dropdown as "select".

If dropdown selected value = "select" then save button should be disabled.

Other wise enabled.

**My Html :**

```
<select class="form-control" name="studymode" ng-model="data.studymode" ng-options="studymode.id as studymode.name for studymode in studymodes" ng-disabled="!eEditMode[$index]">
            <option value="">Select Mode of Study</option>
                 </select>

<button ng-show="saveButton && eEditMode[$index]" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="update('education',$index);" ng-disabled="eForm.$invalid || dataLoading">Save Changes </button>
```

Comment: Could you also post the angular code you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<form name="eForm">
<select class="form-control" name="eForm.studymode" ng-model="data.studymode" ng-options="studymode.id as studymode.name for studymode in studymodes" ng-disabled="!eEditMode[$index]" required> <option value="">Select Mode of Study</option> </select> <button ng-show="saveButton && eEditMode[$index]" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="update('education',$index);" ng-disabled="eForm.$invalid || dataLoading">Save Changes </button>
```

Comment: Thank you i got it

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way as well:

```js
function validate() {
  var submitbutton = document.getElementById("submitbutton");
  var ddl = document.getElementById("selector");
  
  var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
  if (selectedValue == "select") {
    submitbutton.disabled = true;
  } else {
   submitbutton.disabled = false;
  }
}

$( ".form-control" ).change(function() {
  validate();
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  
  <select id="selector" class="form-control" name="studymode" ng-model="data.studymode" ng-options="studymode.id as studymode.name for studymode in studymodes" ng-disabled="!eEditMode[$index]">
  <option value="select"></option>
  <option value="">Select Mode of Study</option>
</select>

<button id="submitbutton" disabled ng-show="saveButton && eEditMode[$index]" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="update('education',$index);" ng-disabled="eForm.$invalid || dataLoading">Save Changes </button>
html angularjs shareeditflag asked 1 min ago Kalaiyarasi M 408 add a comment | show 1 more comment

  
  
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine. BTW I needed to add some id for the selector and button to access them through javascript.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: It is not in angularjs. It is example in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling your save button on a certain value, as you are using a `form`, mark your `select` as [`required`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp). And use a [placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box) for your select.

Then use `ng-disabled`in conjunction with `$invalid` to disable you button until it has a selected value.

Here's an example, apply this to your button :

```
ng-disabled="form.userForm.$invalid"
```

Where `form.userForm` is the `name`of your form.

With this your button will be enabled only if a value is selected.

See [this arcticle](http://www.ng-vinod.com/2014/07/angularjs-pristine-dirty-valid-invalid.html) for information on `$invalid

Answer (score 0):

You can use  data.studymode.length < 1  in your ng-disabled as shown below:

```
<select class="form-control" name="studymode" ng-model="data.studymode" ng-options="studymode.id as studymode.name for studymode in studymodes" ng-disabled="!eEditMode[$index]">
            <option value="">Select Mode of Study</option>
                 </select>

<button ng-show="saveButton && eEditMode[$index]" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="update('education',$index);" ng-disabled="eForm.$invalid || dataLoading || data.studymode.length < 1">Save Changes </button>
```