# Angular select default option with ng-required

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<select id="document" ng-model="document.Id" ng-options="option.Id as option.Name for option in documents" ng-required="IsDocumentRequired">
    <option value="">Please Select Document</option>
</select>
```

The issue is that I don't want this default value ("Please select Document"), to satisfy the ng-required flag when it is set to true.

In summary, I want the user to be forced to choose an option other than the default.

Thanks

Comment: Is this not working now?  The `value=""` `<option>` should make that option not satisfy the `ng-required` already.

Comment: @bboyk see the plunker demo

Comment: Just use `required`. There's no requirements to use `ng-required` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your value is `""` it does not satisfy `ng-required` for select, select's required field validation passes only when select option is not equal to empty, It is designed that way

See the plunker demo, https://plnkr.co/edit/tfeXhHY3h98ItX322JVS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the

```
<option value="">Please Select Document</option>
```

So it wont display it and user should select one item from the list

Comment: Thanks, however I need placeholder text in the select box

Answer (score 0):

You can test the selected value (in your case, I recommend you to put "-1" as value of "Please Select Document").

If the user do not select another value, treat it as an error.

Or see the response in [How do I make a placeholder for a 'select' box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box)