# LocalStorage: Disabled Select Option Rendered Blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm using LocalStorage to remember the value of fields. I noticed however that the default select option (disabled) is rendered blank. How do I render it properly?

**Select Field**

```
<select name="purchasableId" id="metreSelect" class="metre" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select number of metres</option>
    <option value="one">One</option> 
    <option value="two">Two</option> 
</select>
```

**loadStorage Functions**

```
function loadSettings() {
    $("#metreSelect").val(localStorage.setmetre);
}

function saveSettings() {
    localStorage.setmetre = $("#metreSelect").val();

}
```

Comment: If it is disabled, why is it selected?

Comment: it acts as a placeholder giving instructions to the user

Comment: All browsers handle it differently. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box

Comment: When I remove the loadStorage functions then it shows - but I'm using loadStorage to remember the fields (including the placeholder)

Comment: So don't set the value if it is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to save the selected value into localStorage on change of select.

```
$("#metreSelect").change(function(){
    saveSettings($(this).val());
});

function saveSettings(val) {
    localStorage.setItem("selectedMetre",val );
}
```

while loading the page, you need to check for saved value, if available, set that value as selected value

```
loadSettings();
function loadSettings() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("selectedMetre")){
    $("#metreSelect").val(localStorage.getItem("selectedMetre"));
    }
}
```

check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Nageshwar521/z0Lg26oL/)

Comment: Why then does it remember my select option when I choose one?