# Xpages Combobox placeHolder does not work

Tags: xpages

I tried to add "Placeholder attribute into a combobox. I have either an error or It does not work :(

NOTE: I use bootstrap 3.2.0

```
<xp:comboBox id="dRes" value=" {document1.dRes}">
<xp:this.attrs>
<xp:attr name="placeholder" value="Select a value"> </xp:attr>
</xp:this.attrs>
</xp:comboBox>
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that will not work, the 'placeholder' of a combobox is the first item of the combobox or the selected value

Comment: As Frank says - For me, I always compute the first value of my combo's to be something like <Please Select>  If you need to do validation to make sure an option has been selected, then instead of checking for "" or null,  I simply do a check to make sure the value is not <Please Select>