# Select menu placeholder empty value grey text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, placeholder, dropdown, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I'm using this design:

[AdminBSB Material Design](https://github.com/gurayyarar/AdminBSBMaterialDesign)

The design is using `bootstrap-select`. As you can see in the middle of the page, the `-- Please select --` option is an empty value, but the text is black, instead of grey. When using a select menu in a form, all placeholders for all other form elements are grey, instead for the select menu.

I have already checked out all answers given here:

[How do I make a placeholder for a 'select' box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box)

But none of them work for this design. Link for the `bootstrap-select` css:

[AdminBSB Bootstrap Select CSS](https://github.com/gurayyarar/AdminBSBMaterialDesign/tree/master/plugins/bootstrap-select/css)

Does anyone know a solution to show a grey text for empty select menu values? On the bootstrap-select examples page it's working as intended.

[Bootstrap Select Example Page](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/)

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a JSfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net) or CodePen (http://codepen.io)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this section on :
https://gurayyarar.github.io/AdminBSBMaterialDesign/pages/ui/list-group.html

With CONTEXTUAL CLASSES WITH LINKED ITEMS, and other selectbox.

As I see the example are selected, but the color difference between a selected object and a hover object is so small that you can think it is not selected with a high britness screen.

You can change the hover selection with, for example CONTEXTUAL CLASSES WITH LINKED ITEMS, list-group cyan color, by changing the opacity to 0.8 to 0.1:
it is only for **cyan** color this example:

```
.list-group .list-group-bg-cyan:focus{
   opacity: 0.1;
}
```

Hope it helps,

if it is another component please provide an example, or link

Comment: This isn't needed anymore, since I'm using a different design. But I'll accept this answer as accepted :)