# How to add placeholder in ng-repeat dropdown input box?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am implementing one drop-down with ng-repeat. I want to add place holder in input box, Because first time it is blank(without selecting the drop-down option). So I want to set by default placeholder. I don't want leave blank drop-down input box.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names">
</select>

</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placeholder for select with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766564/placeholder-for-select-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an option

```
<option value="" disabled selected>Please Select</option>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["","Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names">
<option value="" disabled selected>Please Select</option>
</select>

</div>
```

Comment: please explain what is the reason for adding empty element at the first position of the array

Answer (score 1):

add an option

```
 <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names">
      <option disabled selected value>Please Select</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set a default value uisng `ng-init` in your select .

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-init="selectedName = names[0]" 
    ng-model="selectedName" 
    ng-options="x for x in names">
</select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this .

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names">
<option value="" selected>Please select</option>
</select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add option disabled here:

```
<option disabled selected value>Select here</option>
```

**Code:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YYxzxj

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names">
  <option disabled selected value>Select here</option>
</select>

</div>
```