# How to add Placeholder to textbox inside select dropdown

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, placeholder, bootstrap-select, jquery-selectbox

[image]

```
 <select   class="form-control selectpicker" id="specialty_id" data-live-search="true"  tabindex="-98" name="specialty_id" >

                                <option selected="" value="0" id="ee" <?php if(isset($_GET['sp_id']) && $_GET['sp_id'] == 0): ?>{{ 'selected="selected"' }} <?php endif; ?>>Choose a Sp</option>
                                  @foreach($searchdropdown['dsp'] as $dsptext)
                                    <option value="{{ $dsptext->spect }}" <?php if(isset($_GET['sp_id']) && $_GET['sp_id'] == $dsptext->spect): ?>{{ 'selected="selected"' }} <?php endif; ?>>{{ $spdata->sp }}</option>

                                  @endforeach

                              </select>
```

How can I add placeholder to that input text in selectbox. That textbox is generated dynamically. I researched about this but unable to found any helpful content. Please help me for this.

for example : Refer this link 
https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#live-search

Comment: Is this what you're searching for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box

Comment: No. I gone through that, But in My case there is editable textbox. @Roman

Comment: Is your code the same as in the example of the link you posted?

Comment: yes.Its in blade of laravel.The options is generating through loop.@Roman

Comment: Do you have the code of the loop or how the select and options are generated?

Comment: updated code @Roman

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this from https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/blob/master/test.html,

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Search" data-actions-box="true">
            <optgroup label="filter1">
              <option>option1</option>
              <option>option2</option>
              <option>option3</option>
              <option>option4</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="filter2">
              <option>option1</option>
              <option>option2</option>
              <option>option3</option>
              <option>option4</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="filter3">
              <option>option1</option>
              <option>option2</option>
              <option>option3</option>
              <option>option4</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. 
I have a solution for you.
Please add the following option to the Jquery function call :

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker(
  {  
    liveSearchPlaceholder: 'Placeholder text'
  }
);
```

I made a CodePen  [live example here](http://codepen.io/yakyrefael/pen/XRmVRG)..

Comment: FWIW, this works as a data attribute on the `<select>` element too, e.g. `data-live-search-placeholder="Placeholder text"`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add data-live-search-placeholder="Example" atribute, to the element ?

Answer (score 0):

For your whole project, you can use jquery code.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

      //selectpicker search placeholder
      $('.bs-searchbox input').attr('placeholder', 
      'Search record..');
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add this data-title attribute in select tag

```
data-title="Search Here"
```

eg.

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-title="Search Here">
    <option>ABC</option>
    <option>DEF</option>
    <option>GHI</option>
</select>
```