# Change Color back to normal in javascript after submitting

Tags: javascript

I am validating one of my forms ,but I have it to check if its empty then it wont go through and the bordercolor will change to red, but after I complete the form correctly the bordercolor will still stay the same. How do I make it where once it submits correctly it will go back to its original state

```js
function convert() {
 var dAmount, currency, total, err = "";

 dAmount = document.getElementById('dAmount').value;
 currency = document.getElementById('Currency').value;

 if (isNaN(dAmount)) {
  err += 'Enter a valid number!<br />';
  document.getElementById('dAmount').style.borderColor = "red";
 }


 if (dAmount == '') {
  err += 'Amount Missing!<br />'
  document.getElementById('dAmount').style.borderColor = "red";
 }


 if (currency == 'Choose') {
  err += 'Please Select a currency!<br />';
  document.getElementById('Currency').style.borderColor = "red";
  return false;
 } else {
  document.getElementById('Choose').style.borderColor = 'gray';
 }


 if (err.length > 0) {
  document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = err;
  return false;
 } else {
  document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'none';

 }






}
```

```css
 #wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 250px auto 0;
 }

 body {

 }

 form {
  width: 580px;
  padding: 10px;
 }

 label {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  clear: left;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
 }

 input, select, span {
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: block;
 }

 input[type="button"] {
  float: right;
 }

 #error {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Final Exam</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="converter.css">
 <script src="converter.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <h1> Currency Converter</h1>
  <div id="error"></div>
  <form id="CForm">
   <label for="dAmount">Dollar Amount: </label>
   <input type="text" id="dAmount" name="dAmount" /> <br />

   <label for="Currency"> Currency: </label>
   <select id="Currency" name="Currency">
    <option value="Choose">Select One</option>
    <option value="British Pound"> British Pound </option>
    <option value="Mexican Peso"> Mexican Peso </option>
    <option value="Euro"> Euro </option>
    <option value="Japanese Yen"> Japanese Yen </option>
   </select>
   <br />
   <label for="Total"> Amount</label>
   <span id="Total"></span>
   <br />

   <input type="button" value="Convert" onclick="convert()" />
   <input type="reset" value="Clear" id="bReset"/>

   </form>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

here is my code

Comment: Instead of setting styles directly add a new class, eg. `.red` with defined red border. When all inputs are filled correctly, just remove `red` class form all these elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add else part to your first two statements or simply use else if statement. As for currency, it is working fine but for the dAmount it is only red as you are not modifying after its color changed.

Answer (score 0):

Let the browser handle this for you with the [`type="number"` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number), [`required` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required), and [`:invalid` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid):

```css
input:invalid, select:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

form {
 width: 580px;
 padding: 10px;
}

label {
 float: left;
 width: 150px;
 display: block;
 clear: left;
 text-align: right;
 padding-right: 10px;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

input, select, span {
 margin-top: 15px;
 display: block;
}

input[type="button"] {
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<form id="CForm">
 <label for="dAmount">Dollar Amount: </label>
 <input type="number" id="dAmount" name="dAmount" required /> <br />

 <label for="Currency"> Currency: </label>
 <select id="Currency" name="Currency" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select One</option>
  <option value="British Pound"> British Pound </option>
  <option value="Mexican Peso"> Mexican Peso </option>
  <option value="Euro"> Euro </option>
  <option value="Japanese Yen"> Japanese Yen </option>
 </select>
 <br />
 <label for="Total"> Amount</label>
 <span id="Total"></span>
 <br />

 <input type="button" value="Convert" onclick="convert()" />
 <input type="reset" value="Clear" id="bReset"/>
</form>
```

The `select` and `option` magic comes from [this SO question about `select` placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box).

See also [MDN's article on form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation).