# How to call HTML required attribute when the value is 0?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have a drop down list where I'm populating data from the database.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Title:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="Title" id ="titleselect" required>
        <!-- <option value="" selected="selected">?</option> -->
        <?php foreach ($titles as $row) {            
            if($this->session->userdata('status')=='active' && $this->session->userdata('Title') == $row->id) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $row->value; ?></option>
     <?php }else{?><option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->value; ?></option><?php } }?>
    </select>
</div>
```

My form,

[image: form]

How values are populated from the database,

[image: how values are populated]

My database table,

[image]

I want to add a validation when the title form is populated with the value "0", which is "?", it should call the HTML required attribute.

Or I would like to disable the option with the '?' mark.

How can I do achieve this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you don't want `0` (`?`) to be considered "valid" for purposes of submitting the form?  This looks like it may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box  Though there are some interesting conversations in the comments about browser comparability.  Looks like it's been helpful to a lot of people though.

Comment: @David, I'm actually looking at something like this. I want to disable the users ability to pick the question mark. Is there anyway that I can achieve this?

Comment: I don't know the php syntax, but in this part: `<option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"` check if id == 0 then output `''` instead of `'0'`. Something like: `$row->id == 0 ? null : $row->id` or `<?php if ($row->id == 0) echo '' else echo $row->id ?>`

Comment: @freedomn-m, this is exactly what I wanted to find out. Can you please add your comment as an answer so it is easy to understand your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution to my issue. I managed to do it without any JS or Jquery. Just added an if statement.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Title:</label>
<select class="form-control" name="Title" id ="titleselect" required>  
<?php foreach ($titles as $row) {                          
          if($this->session->userdata('status')=='active' && $this->session->userdata('Title') == $row->id) { ?>
          <?php  if(($this->session->userdata('Title') == 0)) { ?>
                  <option value="" selected disabled><?php echo $row->value; ?></option> 
          <?php  } else{?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $row->value; ?></option>
          <?php } ?>
<?php }else{?><option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->value; ?></option><?php } }?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery like this: you can use an id for ? like id="yourZeroOption" and then

```
$('option#yourZeroOption').each(function() {
    if ($(this).isChecked())
       $("select").attr("required", true);
     else
       alert('this filled cannot be ?');
});
```

since what you asked was'nt clear enough this code might helf and if you manipulate this code you can get what you want from your code. but this for sure will give you a gist of what you should do. by the way this code does not need to submit it will show the alert before that

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have posted my solution

Answer (score 0):

If this is in Laravel there is a way to catch certain number to be pass. In this case, try with `greater_than` rule with a custom message.

Example

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'greater_than[0]');
$this->form_validation->set_message('greater_than', 'Please select one of these value');
```

**Note:** JS validation works, But keep mind it's not always.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have posted my solution

Comment: @downvoter any comments? However I've reported this to mods regarding serial downvote.

Answer (score 0):

we cant make it require with 0 value it can be done only if `value=""`

here is my idea,

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
<select required>
  <option value="0">?</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
                       $("select option:selected").val("");
   
});
</script>
<style>
```

Comment: However, is there anyway that I can block form from proceeding to the next step instead of colour change? Maybe some JavaScript alert?

Comment: yes you can stop do you  need me to update does it have submit button

Comment: Can you please update. It doesn't have a submit button. It goes to the next part of the form

Comment: give the structure of full `form`

Comment: Do you know whether it is possible to change the value. For example,  if($(this).val()==0), then change the value to "". Then required can be called. I' m looking for something like this

Comment: It still does not seem to work to be honest. Is it possible to add this validation just for this part. For example, the id of my select is "titleselect". Is there a way to call required attribute by just using this id and javascript

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have posted my solution

Comment: i had the same idea like printing directly from PHP at first but ,i thought ou needed it in javascript so...

Answer (score 0):

You should mark your `<select>` field as `required`, then the first option as `disabled` (and `selected`):

```
<select required>
  <option value="" selected disabled>?</option>
  <option value="1">Mr.</option>
  <option value="2">Miss</option>
  <option value="3">Mrs.</option>
</select>
```

This will make the first entry work as a `placeholder` basically.

Comment: This is what I tried in the begging. You can actually see it commented out in my code. When I run this, it automatically skips the option with value = "" and start from 1,2,3 etc. I think this is because I'm querying data from the database. Is it possible to embed the code that I commented out with other option values?

Comment: If you use `value=""`, `selected` and `disabled`, it shouldn't ([see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a2v77u8x/)).

Comment: I know what you mean. However, because of the foreach loop, it selects the option after val = "". So when the form loads, it skips the val ="" and start from val = 0

Comment: Well just don't put it in the DB then, or set `value=""` when `id == 0`, that's it ^^

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have posted my solution