# auto populate select value in form using database value

Tags: php, forms

On my form i am giving user access to modify his details, I am fetching details from db using application id and showing it in my form inputs with its value attribute, so user can see and modify his details if he wants to, but how can we set value in select fields that fetched from database.

here suppose variable is `$country` fetched from db.

```
$country = 'India';
```

And the select fields is

```
<select name="usercountry" id="usercountry">
  <option value="England">England</option>
  <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="India">India</option>
</select>
```

Here I want this select box to be set to `$country` value automatically.

Comment: The attribute you would conditionally add to the `<option>` element is: `selected`

Comment: @SuperDJ : Thank you for the solution mate.

Comment: @imgrv Sure, no problem. I would like to advise you to watch some tutorials on YouTube. For example from codecourse, he makes really good tutorials which are very explanatory, brief but very easy to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This example works form 1 to n number of countries**

```
$userCountry = 'India';

//you get it from DB or wherever
$countries = ['India','USA'];

<select name="usercountry" id="usercountry">
  <?php
        foreach($countries as $country){

         echo '<option value="'.$country.'" '.($userCountry == $country ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$country.'</option>';

        }
 ?>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks ! this is perfectly one what i need, i have more than 15 fields, where users have to select country ! this will reduce the work.

Comment: @SuperDJ : what if i want placeholder here like choose country with NA Value too..

Comment: @imgrv Do you mean a placeholder like `<select placeholder="text here">` ? If that is the case than that is not possible you can however use a `label` or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box. But if that doesn't answer your question please update your question.

Comment: @SuperDJ : No thatss not the exact point, i mean if in my form there is a select field that is not applicable to user and he doesnt want to select it then by default what data will go to db, it will be blank or with some value like first option in select dropdown using the above code.

Comment: @imgrv if not data is selected than it should be blank. However if you use the above select and there is a option selected than this value will return to the db eventough the user didn't alter the select

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

```
 <option <?php echo ($country == 'India')?'selected="selected"':'' ?>>
```

After @Scriptman Comment and suggestion I would like make it more clean

```
<option <?php echo ($country == 'India')?'selected':'' ?>>
```

Comment: That's not clean

Comment: @AniketSahrawat it's a lot cleaner than using a complete if statement and certainly a lot cleaner than including jQuery for something that can be done with vanilla JS

Comment: @SuperDJ So according to you, if there are 1000 option's, then developer should spend his day to write those ternaries?

Comment: @SuperDJ What if the option are generated dynamically? Then you would not might to suggest `eval` right?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat no, I'm not saying that. My guess is that the OP is using this as an example normaly you would do that check and creating the html in a loop.

Comment: You can use `selected` instead of `selected="selected"`. That makes it more "cleaner".

Answer (score 3):

You should check the value of the $country variable to the option value.

```
<select name="usercountry" id="usercountry">
 <option value="England" <?php if($country == 'England'){ echo "selected";}?>>England</option>
 <option value="South Africa" <?php if($country == 'South Africa'){ echo "selected";}?>>South Africa</option>
 <option value="USA" <?php if($country == 'USA'){ echo "selected";}?>>USA</option>
 <option value="India" <?php if($country == 'India'){ echo "selected";}?>>India</option>
</select>
```

Comment: happy to help :)