# In angular 4, how to get id of selected value in select option?

Tags: angular

By using `[(ngModel)]="topic.id"` we can get it but then default value is not shown in dropdown. Do we have any other option to access selected value?

More of my code is given below:

```
<select class="form-control input-lg" name="topicId" ngModel>
    <option value="" disabled>Choose a state</option>
    <option *ngFor="let inquiryTopic of inquiryTopics"
 [ngValue]="inquiryTopic.id" >{{inquiryTopic.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: to give a default value, you can use this.topicId=inquiryTopics[0].id

Comment: yeah but i want default value as "Choose a state" a static string

Comment: Sorry, I read so quickly. Don't work this.topicId=""?. Any way check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box