# Add row manually to eloquent result in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, select, laravel-4, eloquent

I am using Laravel 4.2 and i fetch all  locations with this code:

```
$locations = Location::all();
```

This Locations are displayed in a select box afterwards. How can i add an additional row to the results in order to show an empty first option in the select box.

The options then should be:

- choose a location
- location 1
- location 2
- ...

I just want to add an additional item to the result in $locations.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a placeholder for a 'select' box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box)

Comment: No i want to know how to alter the eloquent result. I know how to do this in pure HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
{!! Form::select('location', ['' => 'Select your location'] + $locations, null , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

to update the view. In Laravel 5 there are [attribute accessors](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) to append an extra field with your eloquent collection.

Few other ways to do this are:

- `$locations[null] = 'choose a location';
  Form::select('location', $locations);`
- `Form::select('location',[null=>'Please Select'] + $locations);`

Another way is to loop through the result and update it. Use `json_decode()` or 'toArray()` to convert your result into array format.

Otherwise you have to store **`choose a location`** as the first row value in your `locations` table(I know that is inappropriate for the requirement).

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the `put` method for collections:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-put

This method is not available in 4.2. You should make a custom Collection class and use it in your model by overwriting the `newCollection` method. https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#collections

Comment: Collections aren't available in Laravel 4.2.

Comment: Looks like you have to make a custom collection class. In the 4.2 docs for eloquent it shows you how.