# how to add placeholder in selectpicker search input

Tags: jquery, html, css

How I can put placeholder in my selectpicker search input, kindly suggest some idea..

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label " for="select"><span class="clrRed">*</span>abc</label>
  <select class="select form-control selectpicker empty" id="existingJob" name="existing-job" data-live-search="true" required>
    <option value="" selected="true" disabled="true" class="placeholder">ht ht ht </option>
    <option value="Job01">Job 01 </option>
    <option value="Job02">Job 02</option>
    <option value="Job03">Job 03</option>
    <option value="Job04">Job 04</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

[image: selectpicker search input]

Comment: try changing `selected="true"` to `selected="selected"` or just `selected`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a placeholder for a 'select' box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box)

Answer (score 2):

data-live-search-placeholder="Search"

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Search">
  <option value="Job01">Job 01 </option>
  <option value="Job02">Job 02</option>
  <option value="Job03">Job 03</option>
  <option value="Job04">Job 04</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a placeholder text in search usingdata-live-search-placeholder
and change select placeholder text using 'title' attribute.

```
<label for="job">Jobs</label>

<select id="job" class="selectpicker" multiple title="Select Jobs" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Search">
    <option>job 01</option>
    <option>job 02</option>
    <option>job 03</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
    <option value="Job01">Job 01 </option>
    <option value="Job02">Job 02</option>
    <option value="Job03">Job 03</option>
    <option value="Job04">Job 04</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://picker.adam-uhlir.me/

or tell me which jquery plugin you are using?

Comment: I using Jquery 3.3.1 -
 https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js