# option disabled selected not set as default value in React js dropdown

Tags: reactjs

In the dropdown below, why is `Select City` not appearing in the dropdown as the default selection on page load ? Instead, `City1` appears as the default selected option.

I have the options for default coded as :

```
  <option value="" disabled selected>
    Select City
  </option>
```

The options are coded in another js file as below:

```
 import React from 'react'

const cityoptions = [
  { value: '1', name: 'City1' },
  { value: '2', name: 'City2' },
  { value: '3', name: 'City3' },
....
```

The following is the component for dropdown.

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Select from '../others/input/select'
import cityOptions from './city-options'

const InputCities = ({ value, change }) => (
  <div className="edit_caste_div">
    <Select
      placeholder="Select option"
      value={value}
      valueChange={e => change('city', e)}
      className="edit_city my2"
    >
      <option value="" disabled selected>
        Select City
      </option>
      {cityOptions.map((e, key) => {
       return <option key={key} value={e.value}>{e.name}</option>
       })}
    </Select>
  </div>
)

InputCities.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  change: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}
```

Comment: maybe because it's disabled, here is an example in pure html https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_disabled

Comment: @OlivierBoissé - makes sense. So how can I show a `Select City` option that is disabled? This is just to prompt them to make a selection but value is meaningless so do not want to allow them to select it. Its basically a greyed out option.

Comment: Actually your example should work because you add the `selected` attribute, here is a similar post https://stackoverflow.com/a/5859221/5521607 maybe this doesn't work because of this `value={value}` on your select element, I supposed the default value is undefined, try to declare your component using a default value : `const InputCities = ({ value = "", change })`

Comment: I created a stackblitz and it's working perfectly using your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rpgzdf How do you declare `<InputCities />` in your code ? with a value probably....

Comment: Your comments helped me find the answer. First I needed to assign value of 0 instead of "". Not sure if thats needed but that is when it worked. Cities were populated based on State selection. So onChangeState (when a new state is selected), I added code to reset city to "0"  -   `changeState = (what, e) => {
    this.setState({ [what]: e.target.value })
    this.setState({ city: '0' })
  }`

Answer (score 1):

You should add a defaultValue attribute to select and set it to the disabled value

```
<Select
      defaultValue="Select City"
      valueChange={e => change('city', e)}
      className="edit_city my2"
    >
      <option value="Select City" disabled>
        Select City
      </option>
      {cityOptions.map((e, key) => {
       return <option key={key} value={e.value}>{e.name}</option>
       })}
    </Select>
```