# Change select option with Angular2

Tags: angular

I want select a option in my select - option in my html with Angular2 , but I need do this for code.

```
<select name="lastDataVi" [(ngModel)]="lastDataVi">
   <option [ngValue]="undefined" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select option</option>
   <option [ngValue]="vicombo.id" *ngFor="let vicombo of paramsServer.vicombo"> {{ vicombo.id}} </option>
   </select>
```

although I have my
`<option [ngValue]="undefined" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select option</option>`

I need when I do click the button , Put the select- option in the frist option ->

`<option [ngValue]="undefined" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select option</option>`

Comment: You just need to assign the selected value to this `lastDataVi`

Comment: but in my html I want that my user see the first option , not that I have the value = undefined"

Comment: still your expected is output is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [value] instead of [ngValue]

```
 <option  *ngFor="let vicombo of paramsServer.vicombo" [value]="vicombo.id"> {{ vicombo.id}} </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
<option selected="true" disabled="true"></option>
```

You need not use ngValue.

Comment: nop. without  ngValue. In html never shows 1º option

Comment: Also you could refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box

Comment: Created a plunker. See if it helps
http://next.plnkr.co/edit/NzQ1skgIrliMIGgEPkp8?p=preview&utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=next&preview