# ReactJS: how to display placeholder on select input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to add placeholder texture to select input using ReactJS, however my current attempt is not working.

My code looks like this:

```
<Input type="select" placeholder="placeholder">
     <option>First option</option>
     <option>second option</option>
     <option>Thrid option</option>
</Input>
```

I am expecting the text "placeholder" to show up on the input field before any option has been selected, however the "first option" is showing by default.

Comment: Where does `Input` come from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a placeholder for a 'select' box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To achieve the placeholder effect on a `<select>` element in ReactJS, first add the `defaultValue` prop to the `<select>` element and preassign a default value of say the empty string. Then, add a disabled `<option>` item with a value that matches `defaultValue` as shown:

```
<select defaultValue="">
     <option disabled={true} value="">placeholder</option>
     <option>First option</option>
     <option>second option</option>
     <option>Thrid option</option>
</select>
```

#### Update

A more robust approach is as follows:

```
<select defaultValue="">
     <option hidden value="">placeholder</option>
     <option>First option</option>
     <option>second option</option>
     <option>Thrid option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: im getting this error `Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>.
 `

Comment: @toymoy Just updated the answer to make this more compatible with reactjs - does that help?

Comment: I tried and not working, still the first option shows up.

Comment: @ChanAustin please see the update in the answer above

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this functionality using
 `<option value="" hidden>`
         Your Placeholder here
 `</option>`

Comment: This has a better behaviour than the other answer to use `disabled` - in this case, the 'placeholder' is not displayed in the options to choose from, even though its disabled.  With this solution, it just isn't there, only the actual selectable values are in the list.