# I need to make an option Choose member to appear before selecting a member

Tags: php, database, dropdown

When my form opens it appears the first row in the database. I want to when opening my form the option Choose member appear first then i select the member.

```
   echo "<select name='member_id' class='form-control' style='width:500px;' >";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

              unset($member_id, $name);
              $member_id = $row['member_id'];
              $name = $row['name']; 
              echo '<option value="'.$member_id.'">'.$name.'</option>';

  }

    echo "</select>";
```

Comment: When opening my form i want "Choose member" appear in the dropdown not the first row value in my database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5859221/1719108

Answer (score 1):

Just echo an option before your while-loop:

```
echo "<select name='member_id' class='form-control' style='width:500px;' >";

// Add it here and it will be first in the list
echo '<option value="">Choose member</option>';

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Your current code
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
   echo "<select name='member_id' class='form-control' style='width:500px;' >";
   echo "<option value='-1' selected='selected'>Choose member</option>";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

              unset($member_id, $name);
              $member_id = $row['member_id'];
              $name = $row['name']; 
              echo '<option value="'.$member_id.'">'.$name.'</option>';

  }

    echo "</select>";
```

You can validate your code by writing:

```php
if($_POST['member_id']) {
//Your code here...
```

Comment: where do i need to input the if($_POST['member_id']) {   for validation

Comment: That has to be in your form processing script, you can just at it to the top of your codes and check if it has been submitted, 
`// Place this atop of your script.
if(isset($_POST))
{
    if($_POST['member_id']) {
        // Your codes here
}
}`

Comment: If the below answer solve your issue, you should accept it so others know the issue has been resolved.