# Change textcolor of selected option in <select>-element

Tags: html, css, select

I have a select-Element with 4 options like this:

```
<select name="selectname">
     <option value="V1" disabled selected hidden>Text1</option>
     <option value="V2">Text2</option>
     <option value="V3">Text3</option>
     <option value="V4">Text4</option>
</select>
```

I want the textcolor of the selected option the be displayed in gray (in the select-box, to let it look like a placeholder). For this i use the following css:

```
<style>
     select:disabled {color: gray; }
</style>
```

But the textcolor of the selected option is displayed in black (standardcolor).

I tried using different attributes in my css instead but this doesn't work as well.

```
select:selected {color: gray; }
select:hidden {color: gray; }
select:invalid {color: gray; }
```

And i have tried using a different keyword:

```
select:disabled {textcolor: gray; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define both select and option in CSS to change the color of your text as you desire.

```css
select {
    color: gray;
}

option {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectname" name="selectname">
  <option value="V1" disabled selected>Text1</option>
  <option value="V2">Text2</option>
  <option value="V3">Text3</option>
  <option value="V4">Text4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: With this the color of the active option appears in gray in the dropdown menu but unfortunately not the pre-selected option on top

Comment: As you can see in code snippet, only first one has text in gray.

Comment: Is this what you mean then?

Comment: No, i want the text, displayed in the selectbox, to be gray (i have edited my question above)

Comment: Every option to be gray or just the first one?

Comment: Not a single one in the dropdown but the one in the select box (the box you see, when nothing is "dropped down")

Comment: Alright, check now, I think that that's what you're looking for.

Comment: If answer helped you, mark the answer with up vote or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29806043/11102792) answer. You should invalidate your placeholder option, by giving it no value and set select to required.