# Forcing a select option to be the same as unselected

Tags: html, forms, drop-down-menu

I have an HTML select form with several options in it. I want a default option of "(select an issue)", but I don't want that option to be submittable. I want the "Please fill out this field" message to show up if the user tries to submit with this option selected.

I've seen this many times on other sites, so I know it's possible, some way or another, but I'm not sure how to approach it.

Comment: Could you please copy and paste your code onto your question?

Comment: Try this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link: [How do I make a placeholder for a 'select' box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box), provided by Jasper Kent, helped me figure it out.

There was a solution to do the following:

```html
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="hurr">Durr</option>
</select>
```

This forces the option to have to be switched before submission, and the user cannot re-select that option either. It also makes it the default selection.